# How to add #hash clicking to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash

When I open my page at http://www.mywebsite.com/ where I have this jQuery code :

```
$('#locSlideButton2').click(function() {

});
```

I'd like, clicking on the `locSlideButton2` element, add an hash (such as #example) to the url, without make any redirect.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Using plain old vanilla JS:

```
window.location.hash='example';
```

[MDN on window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Answer (score 7):

There's two ways, either you use javascript, where you have access to the window.location.hash, or you bind your click event to an `<a href="#example">`, and prevent default on click, or think it's cool when your page goes up to the top, and the hash should appear in the browser adress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Reviving this thread, nowadays you can use `history API`, works the same as above but also avoids automatically scroll to an id, giving you complete control of what you want to do with that hash:

```
window.history.pushState({}, "Example Title", "#example");
```

[MDN on History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

Answer (score -4):

simply wrap `#locSlideButton2' with``  like this

```
<a href="#yourhash"><button id="locSlideButton2">Click me.</button></a>
```

This will do

Comment: a button inside an a element isn't valid html. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393863/600121)

Comment: Ok, just copy/paste this piece of code into the [W3C HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and check it.
`<!doctype html><html lang="en"><title>Test</title><a href="#yourhash"><button id="locSlideButton2">Click me.</button></a></html>`
You'll see it's not valid html.