# jQuery .slideToggle with back/forward button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some steps on my webpage that slide/toggle with click

Code:

```js
jQuery('.lestep1').click(function() {
  jQuery(".content").slideToggle();
  jQuery(".step1").slideToggle();
});


jQuery('.lestep2').click(function() {
  jQuery(".step1").slideToggle();
  jQuery(".step2").slideToggle();
});


jQuery('.lestep3').click(function() {
  jQuery(".step3").slideToggle();
  jQuery(".step2").slideToggle();
});



jQuery('.lestep4').click(function() {
  jQuery(".step4").slideToggle();
  jQuery(".step3").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="step1" id="step1">
  <h1>Step 2</h1>
  <p>Please let us know your employment history from the last 5 years. The most recent employer listed first If you are newly qualified, include your pre- registration year as your most recent employer.</p>


  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="#step1" class="custombutton"> <span class="awsome" style="margin-right: 10px;">&#xf067;</span> Add New</a>
    <a href="#mainLocum" class="lestep1" style="background: #858585;"> <span class="awsome" style="margin-right: 10px;"> &#xf060; </span> Prevstep</a>
    <a href="#step2" class="lestep2"> <span class="awsome" style="margin-right: 10px;">&#xf061;</span> Next step</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="step2" id="step2">
  <h1>Step 3</h1>
  <p>Please answer a few questions to get us know you better</p>

  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="#step2" class="lestep2" style="background: #858585;"> <span class="awsome" style="margin-right: 10px;"> &#xf060; </span> Prevstep</a>
    <a href="#step3" class="lestep3"> <span class="awsome" style="margin-right: 10px;">&#xf061;</span> Next step</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was wondering if I could add some jQuery feature to listing if user clicks back button in his browser or if jQuery read `#tag` in URL (every step have their own hash)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add #hash clicking to an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891370/how-to-add-hash-clicking-to-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the History API  for this.

You would need to add the `history.pushState(null, null, link.href);` to your click functions, and a handler

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    //do some logic here
});
```

You can find a tutorial [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)