# How to make an HTML anchor tag (or link) look like a button?

Tags: html, css

I have this button image:
[image]

I was wondering whether it would be possible to make a simple

```
<a href="">some words</a>
```

and style that link to appear as that button?

If it is possible, how do I do that?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/

Comment: Using CSS I guess ;) http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=style+anchor+tag+like+button

Comment: Users should know by the look of the web interface what its behavior is... so the look of button should not be used as link , and the visual appearance of a link should not be used as a button to.

Comment: Usually you need more than one image for a button: Standard, hovered, pressed, active. Otherwise it will not feel natural.

Comment: I suggest you also add `cursor: pointer;` in css to make the cursor look link a hand with a pointing  index finger, as this also happens with a regular button and is a useful aid to the user.

Comment: By the way, the **Ask Question** 'button' on this very page is exactly what you were asking for.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Using CSS:

```css
.button {
    display: block;
    width: 115px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4E9CAF;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<a class="button">Add Problem</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GCwQu/

Comment: This only works for me if I apply it to `a` tag directly (`a {display: block ...}`), which is not acceptable. Do you have any idea why `class` attribute inside `a` tag won't work? :( I'm using Firefox 27. I also tried `a.button {...}` and it doesn't work either.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap you can do <a class="btn btn-info"></a> and use existing bootstrap styles and avoid defining a new style.

Comment: if you get an underline in your button, add `text-decoration:none`

Answer (score 108):

Check [Bootstrap's docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons). A class `.btn` exists and works with the `a` tag, but you need to add a specific `.btn-*` class with the `.btn` class.

eg: `<a class="btn btn-info"></a>`

Comment: In recent versions of bootstrap you need a specific btn-* class with the btn class. eg: <a class="btn btn-info"></a>

Answer (score 18):

you can easily wrap a button with a link like so `<a href="#"> <button>my button  </button> </a>`

Comment: They should change the spec on this one; it makes the most sense to me.

Comment: You shouldn't use button inside a anchor tag. See this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Answer (score 16):

Something like this would resemble a button:

```
a.LinkButton {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width : 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  text-decoration : none;
  padding : 4px;
  border-color : #000000
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/r7v5c/1/ for an example.

Comment: adding border-radius: 5px; would complete the look.

Answer (score 11):

1. Try this:

   ```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   <div class="container">
     <h2>Button Tags</h2>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Link Button</a>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button</button>
     <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Input Button">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit Button">
   </div>
   ```
2. You can use the a `href` tag line from there.

   ```
   <a href="URL" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Button Text</a>
   ```

Answer (score 7):

If you'd like to avoid hard-coding a specific design with css, but rather rely on the browser's default button, you can use the following css.

```
a.button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
}
```

Notice that it probably won't work on IE.

Comment: For current state of browser support, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance ; note that the browser may render `appearance: button` differently than a native button (at least when I just checked on Chrome 78).

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, but it specifically doesn't work for `<a>` in chrome. Tested it on `<span>` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

None of other answers shows the code where the link button changes its appearance on hover.

This is what I've done to fix that:

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="link_button2">My button</a>
```

CSS:

```
.link_button2 {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #1A4575;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #3A68A1;
  color: #fee1cc;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: larger;
}

a.link_button2:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: #4479BA;
  border: solid 1px #20538D;

  /* optional different shadow on hover
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  */

}
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/adamovic/ovu3k0cj/

Answer (score 3):

Like so many others, but with explanation in the css.

```css
/* select all <a> elements with class "button" */
a.button {
  /* use inline-block because it respects padding */
  display: inline-block;
  /* padding creates clickable area around text (top/bottom, left/right) */
  padding: 1em 3em;
  /* round corners */
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* remove underline */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* set colors */
  color: white;
  background-color: #4E9CAF;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#">Add a problem</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

- Use the `background-image` CSS property on the `<a>` tag
- Set `display:block` and adjust `width` and `height` in CSS

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You have got two options for consistency.

1. Use framework-specific tags, and use them throughout the website.
2. Use JavaScript to emulate a link on a button element, and then have the button consistent with browser's buttons look. Those css button-look hacks will never be accurate.

.

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'Homepage.html'; return false;">My Button</button>
```

`return false;` is to prevent the default behavior of the button being clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that.

Here is an example:

```
a{
    background:IMAGE-URL;
    display:block;
    height:IMAGE-HEIGHT;
    width:IMAGE-WIDTH;
}
```

Of course you can modify the above example to your need. The important thing is to make it appear as a block (`display:block`) or an inline block (`display:inline-block`).

Comment: you should keep the display: inline; and instead of using height and width , you should use padding and line height to adjust the size of the anchor

Comment: @Antagonist: Since the OP wants an image as background and he will most probably always use the same, I dont see why he shouldnt use the specific height and width of that image. But I guess the OP will try all suggested solutions and choose the one that seems best to him.

Comment: what I'm saying is , to use other css properties to achieve the same thing and maintain the original display property to inline ...

Answer (score 1):

For basic HTML, you can just add an img tag with the src set to your image URL inside the HREF (A)

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://problemio.com/img/ui/add_problem.png" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class for the anchor elements that you would like to display as buttons.

Eg:

Using an image :

```
.button {
   display:block;
   background: url('image');
   width: same as image
   height: same as image
}
```

or using a pure CSS approach:

```
.button {
    background:#E3E3E3;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

Always remember to hide the text with something like:

```
text-indent: -9999em;
```

An excellent gallery of pure CSS buttons is [here](http://hellohappy.org/css3-buttons/)
and you can even use the [css3 button generator](http://css3button.net/)

Plenty of styles and choices are [here](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/css3-buttons-10-awesome-ready-to-use-solutions-all-related-tutorials-you-need/)

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Just take regular css button designs, and apply that CSS to a link (in exactly the same way as you would to a button).

Example:

```
<a href="#" class="stylish-button">Some words</a>

<style type="text/css">
.stylish-button {
    -webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 1px 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 1px 0 0;
    box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 1px 0 0;
    color:#333;
    background-color:#FA2;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border:none;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:700;
    padding:4px 16px;
    text-shadow:#FE6 0 1px 0
}
</style>
```

Comment: I've done this on the past projects and IE refuses to behave. I've tested this code, but I would like to state a concern that needs more justification.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Chromium 40 and Firefox 36

```
<a href="url" style="text-decoration:none">
   <input type="button" value="click me!"/>
</a>
```

Comment: This is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

for those having problems after adding active and focus
give a class or id name to your button and add this to css

for example

//html code

```
<button id="aboutus">ABOUT US</button>
```

//css code

```
#aboutus{background-color: white;border:none;outline-style: none;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
<code>

    <a href="#" class="button" > HOME </a>

    <style type="text/css">

        .button { background-color: #00CCFF; padding: 8px 16px; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF border-radius: 3px;}

        .button:hover { background-color: #0066FF; }

    </style>

</code>
```

Watch this (It will explain how to do it) - https://youtu.be/euti4HAJJfk

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to an external website. Links are great for _additional information_, but your post should stand alone from any other resource—links can change or become "dead". Fellow programmers should be able to resolve the problem detailed in the question straight from your answer.

Answer (score -3):

A simple as that :

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" role="button">link</a>
```

Just add "class="btn btn-success" & role=button

Comment: This question doesn't have a bootstrap tag. `class="btn btn-success"` is a bootstrap class.