# Dreamweaver link to button CS6

Tags: button, hyperlink, dreamweaver

OK.. This might be a stupid question but I am a newbie on Dreamweaver. I know that right click -> make link option gives you an option to link a selected text to another page. I was trying to do the same with a button but right clicking a button is not giving the make link button. How do I make a button that when clicked would take me to another page?

I am trying to replicate a google homepage and this is the code I have thus far.

```
<body>
<div align="center">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><img src="logo.jpg" width="281" height="114" /></p>
  <p>
    <label for="textfield"></label>
    <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="" size="100" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="Button 1" type="submit" id="Button 1" value="Google Search" />
    &nbsp;  
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
     <input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="I'am Feeling lucky" />
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention DreamWeaver and I don't know if you want a solution using the GUI side only or if you can go into design view. My answer is about the design view.

Your input type is submit, you need to submit the contents of a form! Something like:

```
<form action="googleResultReplcationPage.aspx" method="get">
  <p>
      <label for="textfield" />
      <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="" size="100" />
  </p>
  <p>
      <input name="Button 1" type="submit" id="Button 1" value="Google Search" />
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
      <input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="I'am Feeling lucky" />
  </p>
</form>
```

To do what you want, you'll need JavaScript and change the type to Button. this obviously only works if the user has JavaScript enabled.

```
<input type="button" value="Google Search" onClick="window.navigate('replicationGooglePage.aspx')">
```

As a work around you could do it using CSS (you will also need to create the hover)

```
<a href="#" class="button">some words</a>

.button {
  display: block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4E9CAF;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357058/how-to-make-a-href-link-look-like-a-button)

Out of these 3 options, the first suggestion is IMO the best way.

As an aside, don't use `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` as it doesn't always work on every browser (some browsers used to only read the first), instead use a style/css and use `Left` or `Padding` or `Margin` (depending on your code/setup/design) - although you would be better off making your [website centered](http://davidwalsh.name/center-website)!

```
<form action="googleResultReplcationPage.aspx" method="get">
  <p>
      <label for="textfield" />
      <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="" size="100" />
  </p>
  <p>
      <input name="Button 1" type="submit" id="Button 1" value="Google Search" />       
      <input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="I'm Feeling lucky" style="margin-left:50px;" />
  </p>
</form>
```