# Get selected data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I already have the SQL Statement for retrieving data from the database, but I dont know how to pass the value from the class that I made to the controller and lastly to the view itself. I have tried to call the method for retrieving data from the database from the class that I made into the controller, and used `ViewBag` --> `ViewBag.Name` for save the value, and pass it to the view like this: `@ViewBag.Name`. When I run, there is nothing to show, like the method for retrieving data is not called.

My question is, how to pass the value from the database and put it into the view?

Here is the code that I am using:

**Controller**:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Update()
{
    ManageUser user = new ManageUser();

    user.GetData(user.Username);

    ViewBag.Username = user.Username;

    ViewBag.EmployeeID = user.EmployeeID;

    return View(user);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(ManageUser user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (user.UpdateData())
        {
            return RedirectToAction("List", "Home");
        }

        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Cannot update to the database!");
        }
    }

    return View(user);
}
```

**View**:

```
@model ProjectName.Models.ManageUser
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Update";
}

<h2>Update</h2>
<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary();

    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Credentials Register</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Username)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @ViewBag.Username
                @Html.DisplayFor(u => u.Username)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.EmployeeID)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @ViewBag.EmployeeID
                @Html.DisplayFor(u => u.EmployeeID)
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Update &raquo;" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel &raquo;" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

**Class (ManageUser.cs)**:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill-in Username.")]
[Display(Name = "Username:")]
public string Username
{
    get;
    set;
}

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill-in Employee ID.")]
[Display(Name = "Employee ID:")]
public string EmployeeID
{
    get;
    set;
}
public void GetData(string username)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string query = "SELECT [Username], [EmployeeID] FROM [User] WHERE [Username] = @Username";

        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username))
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = DBNull.Value;
            }

            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = username;
            }

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Username = reader["Username"].ToString();

                        EmployeeID = reader["EmployeeID"].ToString();
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    reader.Dispose();

                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you including `ViewBag.Username = user.Username;` and `ViewBag.EmployeeID = user.EmployeeID;`? - you have already passed the model to the view and in any case you do not access the `ViewBag` properties in the view. Why does you view have a form? You don't even create any controls (e.g `@Html.TextBoxFor()`) so nothing is ever posted back. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: you are passing empty model i guess try assigning something and pass to view . no need of viewbags . cheers

Comment: `ManageUser user = new ManageUser()` followed by `user.GetData(user.Username);` means your passing a `null` to the `GetData()` method, which in turn means you query evaluates to `"SELECT [Username], [EmployeeID] FROM [User] WHERE [Username] IS NULL"` which I suspect returns nothing so no properties are populated.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I am trying to get the selected data when user click the "Edit" button in the Form. If in ASP.Net Webforms, I can did it, but I am confuse in MVC.  So something like this [Link] (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller), but without using EF, I am trying to get the selected data using SQL query syntax only

Comment: What edit button (you have not shown any edit button in a form).

Comment: `<input type="button" value="Edit &raquo;" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Update", "Home") + "'");" />`

and when I click the Edit button, it goes to the `View` above.

Sorry for not include it when I make a question.

Comment: OK, you appear to be totally confused and have not understood the article you linked to. My best guess to that you want to display a list of all Users on one page, then have a link to open a new page that edits their properties?

Comment: Oh dear. You are really misunderstanding! You need to pass the ID of the user to the `Update()` method (`public ActionResult Update(int ID)`) and then call a method that gets the User based on the ID, then return that to the view. But first you need to get rid of that awful code in your `ManageUser` class and create a separate class in a separate assembly with methods such as `List<ManageUser> Fetch()` - to get all users - and `ManageUser Get(int ID)` to get a single user.

Comment: oh yeah, I didn't see clearly your message there. I just saw `OK, you appear and so on until you have not understood the article you linked to`. Yes sir @StephenMuecke, that is what I mean, I want it to have a link to open a new page that edits their properties.

Comment: There is far too much that wrong with your code to address it all in one answer. I'll will post something a bit later to at least show you how to correctly access the data and return it to the view. You also need to read by first comment - you have a form with cant be edited and wont post back anything

Comment: Please separate your data access method and return the result. Then in GET action call datat access method by passing username and return the User entity. Then cast the User to you view model and return to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly to address why no data is being loaded. In your `Update()` method you first initialize a new instance of ManageUser, whose default value for `Username` will be `null` (the default for typeof `string`). You then call `user.GetData(user.Username);` which passes `null` to the method and based on

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username)) // it is!
{
  cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

your query then returns all Users whose `Username` field is `null`. If you database does not contain any rows where `Username IS NULL` no rows are returned, therefor there is no data to display.

However including this method in your model is bad practice (and what about other methods such as fetching all users?). Start by adding the following 2 classes to your `Data` folder

```
public interface IUserDB
{
  List<User> Fetch();
  User Get(int ID);
}
public class UserDB : IUserDB
{
  public List<User> Fetch()
  {
    List<User> users = new List<User>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
      string query = "SELECT [Username], [EmployeeID] FROM [User];
      conn.Open();
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
      {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
            User user = new User();
            user.Username = reader["Username"].ToString();
            user.ID = reader["EmployeeID"].ToString();
            users.Add(user);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return users;
  }
  public User Get(int ID)
  {
    User user = new User();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
      string query = "SELECT [Username], [EmployeeID] FROM [User] WHERE [EmployeeID] = @ID";
      conn.Open();
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
      {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
          if (!reader.Read())
          {
            return null;
          }
          user.ID = reader["EmployeeID"].ToString();
          user.UserName = reader["Username"].ToString();  
        }
      }
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

Side notes: You do not need to call `Dispose()` - the `using` statement takes care of that. The purpose of the interface may not be obvious yet, but once you gain some experience and understand Dependency Injection it will be. Its not clear why a table named `User` would have a field named `EmployeeID` - it should be `UserID` or better, just `ID`. There is no need to call `if (reader.HasRows)`.

Then change your class to

```
public class User
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill-in Username.")]
  [Display(Name = "Username:")]
  public string UserName { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill-in Employee ID.")]
  [Display(Name = "ID:")]
  public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Notes: A class name should reflect what it is, not what is does - it should not contain verbs such as "Manage".

Now in the controller, you can can call these methods to construct your views

```
public Controller UserController : Controller
{
  UserDB _Repository = new UserDB(); // later you will use DI
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    List<User> model = _Repository.Fetch();
    return View(model);
  }
  public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
  {
    User model = _Repository.Get(ID);
    if (model == null)
    {
      return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

Your `Index.cshtml` view might then look like

```
@model List<yourAssembly.User>
@foreach(var user in Model)
{
  @Html.ActionLink(user.UserName, "Edit", "User", new { id = user.ID }, null)
}
```

Clicking a a link will pass the users `ID` value to the `Edit(int ID)` method which in turn will return the `User` with that ID value.

Note also you `Edit.cshtml` view needs to include controls for editing, i.e `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)`, not `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.UserName)`

Comment: Thank you very much sir, it works! But, I have one question.. I want use button instead of the `TextLink (@Html.ActionLink)`, but how can I change it? I have no idea here. Thank you very much again!

Comment: If you were to use a button, you would need to use javascript/jquery to handle its `.click()` event and perform a redirect, but you can just use css to style your `<a>` tag to look like a button (which is the correct approach)

Comment: sorry, but I dont know how to do it and have no idea at all @Stephen Muecke.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the web of how do do this - [for example this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357058/how-to-make-a-href-link-look-like-a-button). Just inspect the css of your existing button that you want to mimic, then give the `<a>` tag a class name and set the css properties for that class name to match your button

Comment: Thank you @Stephen Muecke, I already can make the `ActionLink` to the `Button` while store the value.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer t his.

Your data access method will be.

```
public ManageUser GetData(string username)
{
    var result=new ManageUser();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
           string query = "SELECT [Username], [EmployeeID] FROM [User] WHERE [Username] = @Username";
           conn.Open();    
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
           {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar);    
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username))
                {
                     cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                }   
                else
                {
                     cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = username;
                }   
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                         while (reader.Read())
                         {                                  
                                result.Username = reader["Username"].ToString();    
                                result.EmployeeID = reader["EmployeeID"].ToString();
                          }
                     }    
                     else
                     {
                          reader.Dispose();    
                          cmd.Dispose();
                      }
                 }
           }
           return result;
  }


        }
```

Your GET action will be

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Update(string username)
{
     ManageUser user = new ManageUser();    
     user =GetData(username);//call data access            
     return View(user);
}
```

Above data access method should be moved to some other place(can be controller as a private method) from Model.

Views remain as it is.

Hope you got it.