# Error while trying populate DropDownListFor from Database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to populate the `DropDownListFor` items from the database, but when I tried to run the program, it gives me error `Object reference not set to an instance`. Like the method (Get data from the database and put it into `SelectList`) did not get called at all, even though I have called and set it from the `Controller`.

Could you please tell me what is going wrong?

Here is the code that I am using:

**Get data from the database: (Inventory class)** (Row Id from table below is there by default when we created the database)

```
private string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

[Display(Name = "ModuleData:")]
public string ModuleData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

public string ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

public SelectList GetData()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> lists = new List<SelectListItem>();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [Query]";

                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            ID = reader["Id"].ToString();

                            Name = reader["Name"].ToString();

                            lists.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = Name, Value = ID });
                        }
                    }
                }

                conn.Close();
            }

            return new SelectList(lists, "Value", "Text");
        }
```

**Controller:**

```
Inventory repository = new Inventory();

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Module()
        {
            repository.ListData = repository.GetData();

            return View();
        }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Module(Inventory inven)
        {
            // There is a button later on and here I want to get the value of a selected `DropDownListFor`
            return View(inven);
        }
```

**View (Module):**

```
@model Project_Name.Inventory
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inventory";
}

<h2>Inventory</h2>
<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Inventory</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.ModuleData)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.ID, Model.ListData)
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

Above is the code that I am using, but once I ran the program, it gives me error on `@Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.ID, Model.ListData)` says that `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

That is all of my question.

Thank you very much

Your answer much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your GET method, your assign the `SelectList` used by `@Html.DropDownList()` using

```
repository.ListData = repository.GetData();
```

however in the when you POST and return the view, you do not reassign the `SelectList`, hence `Model.ListData` is `null`. Your need to repeat the above line of code immediately before your call `return View(inven);`

You also need to return your model in the GET method

```
repository.ListData = repository.GetData();
return View(repository); // change this
```

Comment: What works? Your model is null initially so therefore accessing `Model.ListData` in the view throws an exception (see also Crowcoder's answer), then if you do a POST, you don't reassign the value of `ListData` so its null again. Sorry but your code does not work!

Comment: You get that error because `Model.ListData` is `null` when you return the view in the POST method. See my answer - you need to reassign it again - i.e. add `repository.ListData = repository.GetData();` immediately before `return View(inven);`

Comment: Yes sir @Stephen Muecke, I have found the issue, I did not re-assign the `SelectList` in the [HttpPost] method, that's why when I try to submit the form, the `DropDownListFor` returns null (there is no items inside). Thank you for your answer. Now it is works perfectly :D

Comment: You are also adopting a lot of really bad practices in your code. Your model should not have a method that calls a database. Your need to put the database access code in a separate service which returns a collection of objects (not a `Selectist`) with properties `ID` and `Name` and assign the `SelectList` in the controller. For an example of how your service might look, [refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795557/get-selected-data/30797082#30797082)

Comment: Yes sir @Stephen Muecke, I am aware of that since the last time you told me from my previous question. I will re-create this as when I finish this, and also sir, Storing the data to the database once I pressed the button was successful, but when I get the data from the code that you gave it to me from the previous question, it shows the number instead of text of the `DropDownListFor`. How can I fix that sir @Stephen Muecke? Thank you very much anyway for your effort to help me, I appreciate that :D

Comment: Didn't notice that it was actually your question I linked to :). You mentioned a `DropDownListFor()` but I'm not sure what code you actually used to create the `SelectList`. Based on the previous question, if you were to display a dropdownlist of Users, then it might be `var users = _Repository.Fetch(); var selectList = new SelectList(users, "ID", "UserName");` - but I'm not sure I if I'm understanding correctly, so it would be best to ask a new question.

Comment: sure, will do that (create a new question instead) :)

Answer (score 1):

You are  calling `GetData` but not doing anything with the result. You need to feed the model to the view or else it is null:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Module()
{
    repository.ListData = repository.GetData();
    return View(repository);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Just want to make sure, whenever I doing something in [HttpGet] or getting the data, I have to return the class that I have declared before inside the View also, unless it won't work?

Comment: You don't need to use a Model with GET, but if you need Model data in the View then you must pass the Model to the View. This is not the same as returning the class, you are returning a View.