# How to make HTML button show link in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, button

When you mouse over a `<a>` link, the browser will show you where the link will direct you to if you click on it. For example, in IE, you get like a tooltip at the bottom of the IE window showing the link before you click on it.

I have some pages that use `<button>` instead of `<a>` like this.

```
<button onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/');">Button</button>
```

However, the problem I'm having is that when you mouse over the button, the browser doesn't give you the same information about where it will take you if you click on it. Is there a way I can achieve this behaviour with a `<button>`?

Comment: you can't adjust that. just use a `a`

Comment: While I concur that you should use an `a` if it's a regular old link you want, you can add a `title` attribute for a delayed mouseover tooltip.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp I dont think you can do that anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably best of using an anchor tag and using css to ensure it meets your design requirements (assuming that's why you are using button)
See: [How to make <a href=""> link look like a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357058/how-to-make-a-href-link-look-like-a-button)  for more on making anchor look like button