# Making a link appear like a bootstrap button, fails

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I try to make a link look like a bootstrap button, 
where I use `asp.net` `razor` templating language where I give the link a class of btn only.

I got my inspiration from this question:

[How to make <a href=""> link look like a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357058/how-to-make-a-href-link-look-like-a-button/47831565#47831565)

Yet I don't get my gray formatted button.

Here is my `code`:

```
<a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("viewList","PMGLists",new { id =this.Request.QueryString["pmgID"] })"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></span> Back to PMG List</a>
```

And this is what I get when my so called button / link is rendred.
[Screenshot of 2 buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is67w.png)

Does anyone know what am I missing here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Add these classes to  Your Html file.

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary " ></a>
```

`btn-primary` is Button style

For More reference about Bootstrap Buttons

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp

See the working code in below image.

[image]

Comment: I also tried to use a container but that messed up my layout. Furthermore I would want a gray bottstrap button meaning that only btn should be mentioned in the class.