# How do I pass variable to a Jinja template that was not rendered?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm writing a flask app for a book with many chapters. On the index page I have links to each chapter as: `<a href="/chapters/{{ chapter }}">{{ chapter }}</a>`. My function to render each chapter is:

```
@app.route("/chapters/<chapter>")
def chapter(chapter):
    return render_template(f"chapters/{chapter}.html", chapter=chapter)
```

I separated the layout of the chapter and the text. So my `chapter.html` include the layout and have a block for the actual content:

```
{% include "layout.html" %}

{% block chapter %}{% endblock %}
...
```

While something like `chapter-1.html` extends `chapter.html` and contain the actual text of the book. But now I want to have buttons on `chapter.html` that allows the user to go to the previous/next chapter. Is there a way for me to pass the `chapter` variable from the function to the template `chapter.html` without it being rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@app.route("/chapters/<chapter>")
def chapter(chapter):
    session['chapter'] = chapter
    return render_template(f"chapters/{chapter}.html", chapter=chapter)
```

Use CSS to style an `<a>` tag so that it looks like a [button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357227/4675937) and store the chapter in [sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#sessions).

```
<a href="{{ url_for( 'chapter', chapter=session['chapter'] - 1) }}" class="button-style">Previuos</a>
```

and for the next chapter:

```
<a href="{{ url_for( 'chapter', chapter=session['chapter'] + 1) }}" class="button-style">Next</a>
```

If your chapter value is a string use `chapter=int(session['chapter'])`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know I could use session to store the data. It works great.