# Why this CSS button is not 'clickable'?

Tags: html, css, frontend

So I created a button in html and then styled it in css, but it's not working, I can't click on it.

```css
button.blue {
  background-color: #00FFF0;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<button class="blue" href="www.google.com">Get The App</button>
```

I tried many different combinations, sometimes button just get default html look, sometimes nothing happend. Can someone point me how to create my own custom button? 
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Comment: and the *click* should do what? a button alone will do nothing

Comment: Seems to click fine for me - please can you clarify what you expect it to do when you click it

Comment: @Pete I expect that it got 'effect of click', this little push when clicked or at least hand cursor when hovered

Comment: I think i got it. I added darker color on :hover and cursor: pointer. Now it looks like a button. Thanks for all answers guys

Comment: [Have a look at the styles in this answer (not the accepted one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357058/how-to-make-a-href-link-look-like-a-button#answer-28491102)  it shows how to get that "click" effect

Comment: thanks a lot @Pete ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `button` element can't use a `href` attribute. Use an `A` (anchor) element instead and style it to look like a button as you've just done.

Use the `:hover` `:active` pasuados to change the style when a user hovers or clicks the button.

```css
.btn-blue {
  background-color: #00FFF0;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 1px transparent solid; /* transparent border */
  color: black;
  padding: 13px 30px; /* remove 2px as we are now using the border */
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-blue:hover
{
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #00EEE0;
  border: 1px #99ccff solid;
}

.btn-blue:active
{
  background-color: #00CCC0;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn-blue" href="#">Get The App</a>
```

Now simply replace some of my code above with whatever styles you want.

**UPDATE:**

If you need a button with a fixed height check this code:

```css
.btn-blue {
  background-color: #00FFF0;
  border-radius: 12px;
  
  /* add a transparent border or use #00FFF0 for color */
  border: 1px transparent solid;
  
  /* Allows us to include the padding and border in an element's total width and height. */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  color: black;
  
  /* remove the top and bottom padding, we don't need them */
  padding: 0px 30px;
  
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  
  /* Use this to set a fixed height so the height won't changes */
  height: 35px;
  
  /* Set to same as height so the text is centred in the middle. You can change the font-size or family without the box getting bigger */
  line-height: 35px;
  
  /* So that the box doesn't shrink or expand if the font-size changes on hover like in this example. */
  min-width: 150px;
  
  opacity: 0.6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-blue:hover
{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #00EEE0;
  border: 1px #99ccff solid;
}

.btn-blue:active
{
  background-color: #00CCC0;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn-blue" href="#">Get The App</a>
```

Comment: I would normally advise against using an `onclick` event on a `button` and use the `A` tag instead. While it is 2018 and almost every browser has it, some people have JavaScript disabled either for privacy, security, their organisation doesn't allow it or whatever reason and all you are using it for is a link. Using JavaScript would mean the link won't work if it's disabled.

Comment: ...and you lose basic link functionality like ctrl-click to open in new tab, or right-click and copy URL, which people use all the time with or without JavaScript.

Comment: that's some way, but strange thing happen when I do it - my button is getting removed to border bottom of navbar (it should be centered right, but its getting moved down to bottom border of nav)...

Comment: Probably because I added the border in this code which adds an extra 2px (1px for top and bottom, left and right) so change the padding to `padding: 13px 30px;` other than that we will need to know what navbar you are using, like is it bootstrap? or something custom with a fixed height withh css? see if changing the padding works.

Answer (score 0):

Button don't have a href attribute. you can use 
`<a href="#" > Click Me </a>`
Element.(if you reference any page or link)
Or You can use 
`<button onClick="anyFunction"> Cick me </button>`
 button with event handler which expect a function.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and use css so that it looks like button, because button don't have a href attribute.

```
<a href="#" class="blue">Get The App</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use href in button element. You can use onclick like this.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  button.blue {
        background-color: #00FFF0;
        border-radius: 12px;
        border: none;
        color: black;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 12px;
        opacity: 0.6;  
      }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <button class="blue" onclick="alert('working')">Get The App</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find all html element tutorial in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/)

Answer (score -1):

border: none; makes the problem

please try to give color to the border

eg.

```html
<button class="blue">Get The App</button>

<style>
button.blue {
background-color: #00FFF0;
border-radius: 12px;
border-color: #00FFF0;
color: black;
padding: 15px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 12px;
opacity: 0.6;  }
</style>
```

Comment: Are you seriously saying that the difference between a clickable and non-clickable button is its border color?

Comment: No i mean the button feels not clickable because border:none;

Comment: nice try, but when i remove it, it changes its look

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is about the button not working as a link, not how it "feels".