# I cant get a button to link to sending an email

Tags: html, css, spiceworks

I am making a meet the staff page for our help desk. Even with everything looking good i am really struggling to make the contact button clickable to send an email. i can easily add a linkable option to email but that looks tacky. i have a feeling its as esy as moving my a tag around but it doesnt seem to work for me where ever I place it im not a very experienced code writer the way it is.

```html
<style type="text/css">/* Three columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

/* Display the columns below each other instead of side by side on small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* Add some shadows to create a card effect */
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Some left and right padding inside the container */
.container {
  padding: 0 16px;
}

/* Clear floats */
.container::after, .row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.title {
  color: grey;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
</style>
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
<div class="card"><img alt="Amy" src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%" />
<div class="container">
<h2>Amy</h2>

<p class="title">IT Manager</p>

<p>Some text that describes me lorem ipsum ipsum lorem.</p>

<p><a href="mailto:amyh@.org?subject=%5B%20Spiceworks%20%5D%20-">amyh@.org</a></p>

<p><button class="button">Contact</button></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
<div class="card"><img alt="Vincent" src="https://ibb.co/N6VjMjD" style="width:100%" />
<div class="container">
<h2>Vincent</h2>

<p class="title">IT Specialist</p>

<p>Some text that describes me lorem ipsum ipsum lorem.</p>

<p><a href="mailto:vincentw@?subject=%5B%20Spiceworks%20%5D%20%-">vincentw@</a></p>

<p><button class="button">Contact</button></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the "contact" buttons to do the same thing as the `mailto` links?

Comment: Yes. Then I will remove the links above the button and have more room for a about me section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using CSS to style your `<a>` elements like you have the `<button>` elements styled.
Something like this:

```
<a href="mailto..." class="button">Contact</a>

.button {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Here's a demonstration:

```css
/* Three columns side by side */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0 8px;
}


/* Display the columns below each other instead of side by side on small screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}


/* Add some shadows to create a card effect */

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Some left and right padding inside the container */

.container {
  padding: 0 16px;
}


/* Clear floats */

.container::after,
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.title {
  color: grey;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="column">
    <div class="card"><img alt="Amy" src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%" />
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Amy</h2>
        <p class="title">IT Manager</p>
        <p>Some text that describes me lorem ipsum ipsum lorem.</p>
        <p><a href="mailto:amyh@.org?subject=%5B%20Spiceworks%20%5D%20-" class="button">Contact</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="card"><img alt="Vincent" src="https://ibb.co/N6VjMjD" style="width:100%" />
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Vincent</h2>
        <p class="title">IT Specialist</p>
        <p>Some text that describes me lorem ipsum ipsum lorem.</p>
        <p><a href="mailto:vincentw@?subject=%5B%20Spiceworks%20%5D%20%-" class="button">Contact</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'll try first thing in the morning. Looks very similar to something I tried but I didn't do the class=

Comment: You might also find these interesting: [How to make <a href=“”> link look like a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357058/how-to-make-a-href-link-look-like-a-button) and [Styling Links Like a Boss](https://css-tricks.com/css-basics-styling-links-like-boss/).

Comment: worked beautifully I had everything right except for 'class=button' thanks is it possible to make the images standard size they fit width wise but are really long otherwise

Comment: That might be best posted as a separate question. What size are the images and what at what size would you like them displayed? (I can't see any of them.)

Comment: nvm i worked on it last night forgot i added a var height tag alongside the 100% width