# Is there a way to make buttton pressable while cursor near to button?

Tags: css

I was trying to make webrazzi from scratch.I want to press the buttons while cursor nearby to I also want to press the button.(In the image you can see red rectangles.I also want to add a place like that and can press the button If I am even there).(Sry for bad english)

Image: https://prnt.sc/oaewro

I tried to make a tags block but when I did that search button comes under "Search" text

```css
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 2.4rem;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(2) a{
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #0A0A0A;
  font-size: .9rem;
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Search</a><i class="fas fa-search"></i></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: put `<i class="fas fa-search"></i>` inside `a`

Comment: I know this sounds odd but can you try setting the margin of the left and right up abit?

Answer (score 0):

Give your anchor elements a width and height.

```css
.button {
    display: block;
    width: 115px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4E9CAF;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" onClick="javascript: alert('hello')">Say Hello</a>
```

Above is an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357227/4185234) answer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid rebeccapurple;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #0A0A0A;
  font-size: .9rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Search <i class="fas fa-search"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: A code dump is not helpful. Please explain your answer and why it works, how it solves the OP’s problem, and what the OP was doing wrong. Consider including references and working examples. This is just a wall of code.

Comment: ya you are right. I am giving a proper explanation