# How to change this <a> link into a button?

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code there is a link:

```
<textarea placeholder="input" id="input"></textarea><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="file name" id="filename"/><br>
<a href="#" id="export">Export</a>


<script>
var container = document.getElementById('input');
var anchor = document.getElementById('export');

anchor.onclick = function() {
    anchor.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(container.value);
    anchor.download = document.getElementById('filename').value;
};
</script>
```

How can I change the **Export** link into a button with the same id and fuction?

Comment: What do you mean by change? You can just wrap `button` in `anchor` tag

Comment: Probably this,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357058/how-to-make-a-href-link-look-like-a-button

Comment: Why can't you just style the `<a>` as a button? What specific problem are you trying to solve here? As a new user I would suggest you take a few minutes to thoroughly read through [ask] then edit the question with clarifications

Comment: @JózefPodlecki thanks, will try that.

Comment: @JózefPodlecki — No, you can't. It is forbidden to put `<a>` elements inside `<button>` elements.

Comment: Consider dropping the data URI.  You're going to hit size limits pretty quickly.  Create a blob instead.

Comment: please accept an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var hello = () => { // this is equal to write " var hello = function() { " and to write " function hello() { "
 alert('hello')
}
```

```css
.link {padding: 10px; color: white; background: #00ced1; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 5%}
.link:hover {opacity: 0.8}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#" onclick="hello()">Hello</a>
```

u can do something like this, (this is very simple, just an example) 
however this is a very basic thing, please, first of posting a question consider reading the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Change your anchor tag to a button.

`<button id="export">Export</button>`

Now, inside the `onclick` handler, create a anchor with the desired attributes, and invoke the click method on it. This way you gonna activate an anchor click when you click the button.

```
<script>
    var container = document.getElementById('input');
    var button = document.getElementById('export');

    button.onclick = function() {

      var anchor = document.createElement('a');

      anchor.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(container.value);
      anchor.download = document.getElementById('filename').value;
      anchor.click();
    };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<textarea placeholder="input" id="input"></textarea><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="file name" id="filename"/><br>
<a href="#" id="export" class="btn btn-secondary">Export</a>


<script>
var container = document.getElementById('input');
var anchor = document.getElementById('export');

anchor.onclick = function() {
    anchor.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(container.value);
    anchor.download = document.getElementById('filename').value;
};
</script>
```