# Making a button that’s send you to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, authentication

Hi i am trying to make a button that’s works like a link. I hope it makes sense, can you help?

```
<button type="submit"  value="Login" id="next" class="login-form-submit next" href="lessonB.html">Next</button>
```

Comment: An `<a>` tag as a nested element to `<button>` is technically invalid: `Error: The element a must not appear as a descendant of the button element.`  Instead, style the `<a>` in a manner to make it "look like" a button instead. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8357227/7644018)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking you have a form you are submitting with this button. It's not the right solution in your case to add a  element inside the button. Here an example of how I would do it:

```
<form action="https://redirect_link_here.com/foo.html" method="GET">
   <input name="name">
   <input name="lastname">
   <button type="submit">Button name</button>
  </form>
```

When you press the button the user input gets sent to the link you specified in action in the URL. So if the user inputs is "Andreas" and "Köhler" for instance you would be redirected to this URL on submit: https://redirect_link_here.com/foo.html?name=Andreas&lastname=Koehler. Then you can read the data out of the URL in the code of foo.html and your submit button is not messed up.

Comment: Thanks but its what I’m lookin’ for

Comment: @Dropnothing So if thats what your lookin' for then you could accept the answer

Comment: But can i just put it on the button?

Comment: @Dropnothing put what on the button?

Comment: The action attribute

Comment: @Dropnothing sorry for the delay was away from home. But no you can't put the action attribute on the button. You need to put it on the form. But the action will be exectuted once you press the submit button