# Cant seem to get Angular Routing working on some occasions?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have been attempting to get angular routing working and everytime I create a new project and It does not work. I have had it working in some projects but I can never see why my newly created project does not work.

Its probably something obvious, thanks for any help in advance.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Content/Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

       <a href="#/">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Homepage</button></a>
    <a href="#/about">
        <button class="btn btn-success">About</button></a>
    <a href="#/date">
        <button class="btn btn-warning">Date</button></a>


        <div class="row">
            <div ng-view>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="SinglePageApp/app.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>

    app.js file


    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        //default page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: "pages/homepage.html",
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        })
    //about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: "pages/about.html",
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
    })
    //date page
    .when('/date', {
        templateUrl: "pages/date.html",
        controller: 'DateCtrl'
    });
    });

    app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.homepage = "Homepage";
    }]);

    app.controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.about = "Lorem ipsum............";
    }]);

    app.controller('DateCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.dateNow = new Date();
    }]);
```

Comment: What is the URL you are using?  What are the errors?

Comment: are angular and angular-route the same version ?

Comment: It has started working again, It was my directory layout, Is there a specific layout folders need to take for routing to work??

Answer (score 0):

Try this plunker:

http://embed.plnkr.co/L6E4GCe3O0Jh1vqKyGFD/

I've used the example at [the angularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example) to create your usecase.

You should change the template filepaths, with your own. I also haven't included bootstrap.

If you want to use buttons, then you can use [this example in plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/FExYMp3nagO1HHCwhd02/) [based on this answer by Josh David Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847726/is-there-a-simple-way-to-use-button-to-navigate-page-as-a-link-does-in-angularjs)(upvote him if you use his directive). Directives are a way to customize html, and here we're using one as an html attribute (you can also use them as standalone elements) to create a hyperlink button.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's fiddle for you that works as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/39unq8yh/1/)

Not sure why your code is not working, angular has pretty bad debugging tool.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-route.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#/">
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Homepage</button>
  </a>
  <a href="#/about">
    <button class="btn btn-success">About</button>
  </a>
  <a href="#/date">
    <button class="btn btn-warning">Date</button>
  </a>
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="pages/homepage.html">
  {{homepage}}
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="pages/about.html">
  {{about}}
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="pages/date.html">
  {{dateNow}}
</script>
```

Script file looks like this

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
  app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    //default page
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: "pages/homepage.html",
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    //about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: "pages/about.html",
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
    })
    //date page
    .when('/date', {
        templateUrl: "pages/date.html",
        controller: 'DateCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
 });
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.homepage = "Homepage";
}]);

app.controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.about = "Lorem ipsum............";
}]);

app.controller('DateCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.dateNow = new Date();
}]);
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```