# Nesting <a> inside <button> doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I have a `<button>` with a hyperlink tag inside, looks like this:

```
<button class="btn"><a href="#"></a></button>
```

This works well in Chrome and Safari, BUT doesn't work in Firefox (ver 20 tested).

What's wrong?

Comment: Why would you have the code like that? Having an anchor inside a button tag is not correct HTML afaik. It would seem better to simply style the anchor tag to look like the button style you want and get rid of the button tag altogether.

Comment: hahahahahah... why i didn't thought of that before :P , had been months coding like that :S

Comment: yeah, Bootstrap is quite happy to accept all of the "btn" classes on anchor tags as I've shown in my answer below :)

Comment: Except anchors aren't keyboard-navigable like buttons are.

Comment: Wrapping a button around an anchor fails both the WHATWG and W3C validators (html5.validator.nu and validator.w3.org).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link inside a button not working in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253410/link-inside-a-button-not-working-in-firefox)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

To make it work in all browser,  Firefox too you have to change it to

```
<a href="#"><button class="btn"></button></a>
```

or as suggested by Billy Moat in case of bootstrap there was no need of `<button>` you could just do

```
<a href="#" class="btn">GO</a>
```

Comment: Right, but FYI - the first option breaks the styles when using a button group in bootstrap.  :(

Comment: @HussienK but why?

Comment: Wrapping a button in an anchor fails both the WHATWG and W3C validators (https://html5.validator.nu/ and https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Anchors alone aren't as fully keyboard-navigable as buttons are.

Comment: This seems to be breaking the rules. Buttons cannot be nested inside anchor tags. 
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5/6393863

Answer (score 22):

Probably better to just do this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn">Go!</a>
```

Comment: Except anchors aren't as fully keyboard-navigable as buttons are.

Answer (score 3):

This issue  is happening in FF and IE(< 10).
The browser simply doesn't like the tag button when it's used as a link.

Quick solution in bootstrap is to use  and give a class of btn btn-default (or your choice of button style).

However, you can use  in a form (submit button for instance) and you shouldn't have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an onclick method instead of changing the HTML structure, if you can't change your structure because of something that doesn't allow you to change(e.g. bootstrap components as list-groups, that's my case hehe) and mainly if you want to put two or more links inside a button:

```
<button class="btn"><a onclick="location.replace('YOUR_URL_HERE')"></a></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using **wordpress** `wp_loginout` function. This function create a link for login/logout to nest the link inside a button for styling eg: using `btn` `btn-primary` just replace the `<button>` tag it with a `<span>` tag

```
<span class="btn btn-primary"><?php wp_loginout($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ); ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesting an `<a>` tag inside a `<button>`, or vice versa, violates HTML rules and will not pass a code validator:

"The element `<a>` must not appear as a descendant of the `<button>` element."

If you want your button to behave like a link, or your link to look like a button, you can style your link to look like a button with CSS or Bootstrap, as shown by Billy Moat's answer,

OR

you can use `location.href` in the button tag:

```html
<button onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com'" type="button"> www.example.com </button>

<button onclick="window.location.href='/css_page.html'">CSS page</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me to retain bookstrap btn-group stylings:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.replace('YOUR_URL_HERE')">Click Me</button>
```