# IE dynamically generated link using jQuery not linking

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I generated an HTML button in jQuery that points to a page, it's appended to the end of a div.  I'm able to click the button and go to the page in all browsers except IE, anyone know why that might be?  The button shows in IE and is clickable, just doesn't take me to the page.  Here is the code:

```
$("div.class:last-child ol").append("<button class='class'><a href='http://www.page.com' target='_blank'>Apply Here</a></button>");
```

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280684/nesting-a-inside-button-doesnt-work-in-firefox

Comment: Also maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: Probably best to choose just the `a` or `button` tag, and style the rest.

Comment: future reference:  when referring to "IE" it's useful to include the version you tested on

Comment: It was just a button issue...  Changed it to a div and it's all good, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You are putting a `<a>` inside a `<button>`. It's not a good way. You can append `<a>` to the `$("div.class:last-child ol")` **directly**:

```
$("div.class:last-child ol").append("<a class='class' href='http://www.page.com' target='_blank'>Apply Here</a>");
```