# Buttons Not Clickable in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

It recently came to my attention that the agency I work for that the `<button>` elements are not clickable.

The way the markup is the following:

```
<button><a href="javascript:void(0)"Text</a></button>
```

It works fine in all other browsers, but buggy ol' FireFox isn't getting along with it.

Here's the link to the page we discovered it on, try clicking on either in FireFox, and also Chrome. See how it's supposed to behave, but isn't in FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `<a></a>` it's not allowed inside of a `Button` see the [`the-button-element documentation`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element), then you can't depend on having the links as a children of the `button`.

You have to use another element to contain the `<a>`.

If you want to do some tricks you can do this :

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><button>Text</button></a>
```

For more information check those [*answers*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280684/nesting-a-inside-button-doesnt-work-in-firefox)

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, you should be voting to close it as such, not answer it.

Comment: The "duplicate" doesn't use JavaScript... anyways I don't think that's a reason to downvote thoug :).

Comment: So let me get this straight, you think that two problems that have the same exact markup except for the fact that one of them has a little bit of javascript can't possibly be duplicates, even though the answers to both questions are identical?  That's the literal meaning of duplicate.  And yes, the downvote is entirely warranted:  you should not be answering duplicates, *especially* when you know they are duplicates.

Comment: In addition, your solution is illegal too: just like it's not allowed to have an <a> in a <button>, the other way around is not allowed either.

Answer (score -1):

You can not put a `<a>` within a `<button>`. I suggest that you change your code to one of the following:

```
<button onclick="javascript:void(0)">Text</button>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Text</a>
```

Comment: Ok, just to be clear,the href="javascript:void(0)" was only meant to be in lieu of an actual URL in there.

Comment: I ended up just switching the <button><a></a></button> structure to an <a> wrapped in spans. Got to love find and replace for templates and mixins for easy updates.