# Jquery "before" add close tag of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have following HTML element:-

```
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/post-2/#more-4" class="more-link">
```

I tried to add a button before `span` (put `span` between button) with jQuery before function:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.more-link").before("<button class=\"btn btn-default\">");
    }); 
</script>
```

The output is:

```
<button class="btn btn-default"></button>
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/post-2/#more-4" class="more-link">
    <span aria-label="Continue reading post 2">(more…)</span>
</a>
```

The following `</button>` tag is added automatically! Why? Can I not add a `span` between button tags? How can I prevent that or is there any way to add span between button tags?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.more-link").before("<button class=\"btn btn-default\">");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-default"></button>
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/post-2/#more-4" class="more-link">
    <span aria-label="Continue reading post 2">(more…)</span>
</a>
```

Comment: You can only add whole elements to the DOM. If you want to add a `span` inside the button, you can just `append()` it in the same way you create the button. What is the HTML output you're trying to create?

Comment: Also note that you cannot have an `<a>` element inside a `<button>` if that is your intent.

Comment: @Anant, yes. it works in firefox and chrome

Comment: @MahsumAkbas  so if you got answer then mark+up-vote that answer. you can up-vote others too if they are useful. If still have problem then let us know.

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a tag without close it that not a valid HTML, so the browser will always validate your HTML code by adding the closed tag.

If you want to wrap your span by button you could add it in your js using the jQuery method **[`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)** :

```
$( "a.more-link" ).wrap("<button class='btn btn-default'>");
```

**NOTE :** If you do so your HTML isn't valid since you shouldn't put an anchor `a` inside a `button` tag.

(PLEASE TAKE A LOOK TO **[Nesting `<a>` inside `<button>` doesn't work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280684/nesting-a-inside-button-doesnt-work-in-firefox)**).

Hope this helps.

```js
$( "a.more-link" ).wrap("<button class='btn btn-default'/>");

console.log ( $('button')[0].outerHTML );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/post-2/#more-4" class="more-link">My link </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "a.more-link" ).before( "<button class=\"btn btn-default\"><span>I'm a span</span></button>" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/post-2/#more-4" class="more-link">
```

Answer (score 0):

zakaria is right you can't open a tag without closing it, wrap span within button, use this

```
$( "a.more-link span" ).wrap("<button class='btn btn-default'>");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $( "a.more-link" ).wrap( "<button class=\"btn btn-default\">" );
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot place an `<a>` within a `<button>` element.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you exactly need, but try if `wrap` function is what you are looking for:

```
$( "a.more-link" ).wrap( "<button class=\"btn btn-default\">" )
```

Comment: You cannot place an `<a>` within a `<button>` element.