# Firefox Not Opening HTML Links, Chrome & Edge Work

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, mozilla

I've run into a problem I have never seen before with my site. I have 'a' links that go to other pages in the site, and they work perfectly in Edge, Chrome, and Safari, but Firefox won't open them. I just tap away and nothing happens.

My Nav CSS For the Issue:

```
.navigation {
width: 75%;
position: relative;
left: 13em;
top: 3em;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.dropbtn {
background-color: transparent;
color: white;
font-size: 34px;
font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #680b1e;
}

#about {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin-left: 40px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="about">
<button class="dropbtn"> <a href="about.html"> Book </a> </button>    
</div>
```

Comment: It happens when you don't read html rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the HTML, `a` is not allowed to inside `button`, see this question for more details:

[Link inside a button not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253410/link-inside-a-button-not-working-in-firefox)

A possible workaround could be to use the `click` event on the button to change `window.location` (using javascript), but it's not really recommended, again check the question I linked for more details about the workarounds and fixes.

Comment: Also check the fix on this other question [Nesting a inside button doesn't work in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280684/nesting-a-inside-button-doesnt-work-in-firefox)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up I had no idea about 'a' not working in a button.