# Can't seem to change text color using HTML on these buttons

Tags: html, button, text, colors

The following is the code I'm using. I'd like both buttons to be white in colour, but can't seem to get that to work. I'm customizing a bloom (by divi) popup on wordpress.

```
<div>
<style>
.btn-group button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: 1px solid green; 
  color: #FFFFFF; 
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left; }
</style>

<body>
<div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
  <button style="width:50%"><a href="----">In-Store Visit</a></button>
  <button style="width:50%"><a href="-----">Eye-Exam</a></button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
       </div>
```

Comment: Try to taget the `a` tag insted? `.btn-group button a{ color:#FFF;}`

Answer (score 0):

That is a link, which is pose in <a>,

```
a{color: #FFFFFF;}

/* Bloom */

a:hover, a:active{color: #FFFFFF;text-shadow: 0 0 4px #FFFFFF;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have a `<a>` element inside the `<button>`, those have a default color in every browser (that's the blue color that you are getting right now).
You need to have a rule to tell the `<a>` to change color to the one you want:

```
.btn-group a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Have in mind that you need to add colors for :hover, :active, :visited, etc.

Not related but important: this patter of an `<a>` inside a `<button>` it's not quite semantic, and won't work in Firefox ([Nesting <a> inside <button> doesn't work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280684/nesting-a-inside-button-doesnt-work-in-firefox))

I would change the code to something like this:

```
<div>
<style>
.btn-group a {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: 1px solid green; 
  color: #FFFFFF; 
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="btn-group" style="width:100%">
  <a style="width:50%" href="----">In-Store Visit</a>
  <a style="width:50%" href="----">Eye-Exam</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</div>
```

Comment: different question, i guess, but how would I separate the two buttons so they don't look the same?

I'm thinking if there is a way to add divide the background somehow?

Comment: Honestly I would try to approach this with flexbox. It's a much better technique for aligning elements. Example: https://codepen.io/sergiofruto/pen/MWyqEmN