# Remove underline between button and link

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML link

```
<a href='#'><button>+</button> Show advanced options</a>
```

which reveals the hidden options upon clicking the button or link. The problem is that there is an underline between the button and the text (just the one character before "Show".) Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: Move the button outside of the link (I'm pretty certain it's invalid to nest interactive elements, regardless of the CSS problems.)

Comment: Can you close the anchor after the button and open it up?

Comment: @DavidThomas I want the button to be part of the link

Comment: Button inside anchor is not valid html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: @the_lotus: thanks, I was about to Google for a resource to back up my assertion. =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

style the hyper link

```
a {text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

use css `text-decoration` property :

```
<a href='#' style='text-decoration:none;'><button>+</button> Show advanced options</a>
```

but button inside an anchor tag is invalid

you can use onclick event for the button

Answer (score 0):

A button tag inside an a tag is not valid. This line comes from the w3 validator:

```
The element button must not appear as a descendant of the a element.
<a href="test"><button>a</button></a>
```