# Bootstrap : Add a button link in the bottom right corner of a thumbnail

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I want to do something like that :

[image]

For now, I'm using margin but I'm sure there is some "clean" method to do that... :
http://jsfiddle.net/vXMMA/445/

```
<ul class="media-grid">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/140x90" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" style="margin-left:-23px;margin-top:67px;">+</a>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a href="#">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/140x90" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" style="margin-left:-23px;margin-top:67px;">+</a>
  </li>       

</ul>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this

```
<ul class="media-grid">
  <li>
    <a href="#" style="position:relative;">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/140x90" alt=""/>
        <button class="btn" style="position:absolute;bottom:5px;right:5px;margin:0;padding:5px 3px;">+</button>
    </a>
  </li> 
  <li>
    <a href="#" style="position:relative;">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/140x90" alt=""/>
        <button class="btn" style="position:absolute;bottom:5px;right:5px;margin:0;padding:5px 3px;">+</button>
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xKrXn/1/

Comment: But this isn't really Bootstrap-specific, and the problem is, this isn't really responsive, which is one of the main points of using Bootstrap.

Comment: This isn't valid HTML in that you shouldn't have a `button` within an `a` element. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5. Instead, you can make them siblings within the `li`.

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
ul.media-grid li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 6px;
}

.media-grid a {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vXMMA/446/

Comment: I'm not a css expert, but the both solutions works, but on all web browser ?