# How to add a close icon in bootstrap tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

I want to add a close icon in bootstrap tabs and then I can close the tab by click the icon.

I try below but the "X" is displayed not on the same line as tab title.

```
.close {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #000000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.2;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline;
}
.close:hover {
    display:inline;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    cursor: pointer;
}

<a id="user-list-tab-li" style="display:inline;" href="#user-list-tab-pane">The tab</a> 
<span class="close">×</span>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

the working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/pb6EM/1/)

```
 function registerCloseEvent() {

$(".closeTab").click(function () {

    //there are multiple elements which has .closeTab icon so close the tab whose close icon is clicked
    var tabContentId = $(this).parent().attr("href");
    $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //remove li of tab
    $('#myTab a:last').tab('show'); // Select first tab
    $(tabContentId).remove(); //remove respective tab content

});
 }
```

Comment: i think its better to use hide(). si it easier to show() it again.

Comment: -1 for fiddle example, where you put <button> inside <a>. Why we don't want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: I would add a check to see if the to-be-removed tab is currently displayed before displaying the last one:

`if ($(tabContentId).is(":visible"))`

Comment: @m_david what is the alternative if you want the button to appear on the tab as shown in the fiddle, but want to avoid `<button>` inside `<a>`? See my related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403406/close-button-in-bootstrap-tabs-without-putting-button-inside-a

Answer (score 10):

Try to put the span-tag inside the a-tag:

```
<a id="user-list-tab-li" style="display:inline;" href="#user-list-tab-pane">The tab<span class="close">×</span></a>
```

And if you use bootstrap include an icon like this:

```
<i class="icon-remove"></i>
```

Comment: The issue is that even though the close button was clicked, an event is sent to the <a> tag because that is clicked as well.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`should handle this case.

Comment: yep I know, I'm just saying that there is something to watch out for as well, and just not `return false;` because that does other things in addition to preventing the default actions.

Comment: I've used this solution, but `event.preventDefault()` was not what I needed: to stop the parent `<a>` tag registering the event I had to use `event.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

Small tweaks to [Vinod Louis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18096854/1308967)'s answer - relative link to the `li` list and only `show` a tab if it is the current one closing.

```
function close_tab (tab_li)
{
    var tabContentId = $(tab_li).parent().attr("href");
    var li_list = $(tab_li).parent().parent().parent();
    $(tab_li).parent().parent().remove(); //remove li of tab
    if ($(tabContentId).is(":visible")) {
        li_list.find("a").eq(0).tab('show'); // Select first tab
    }
    $(tabContentId).remove(); //remove respective tab content
}
```

Then attach:

```
$(".closeTab").click(close_tab(this));
```

Or:

```
<button class="close closeTab" type="button" onclick="close_tab(this)" >×</button>
```