# How to customize tabs on react-bootstrap customize

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap from this site : http://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html

And I would like to know how to custom a tabs like this one (in the tabs section):

```
const tabsInstance = (
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey={2}>
    <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">Tab 1 content</Tab>
    <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">Tab 2 content</Tab>
    <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3" disabled>Tab 3 content</Tab>
  </Tabs>
);

ReactDOM.render(tabsInstance, mountNode);
```

I want to add a cross button to close it but I didn't find how to do that. Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see that the behavior you want is supported by default by Bootstrap and this React wrapper.  The technique I would recommend is to extend the Tabs component to do what you want which is found here:
https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Tabs.js

Take a look at how others have added this behavior in older version of Bootstrap using things like JQuery: 
[How to add a close icon in bootstrap tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096724/how-to-add-a-close-icon-in-bootstrap-tabs)

Use that to give yourself an idea and then either create a new component or extend the existing Tabs component using composition: [Extending React.js components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720595/extending-react-js-components)

Comment: Thanks for your ideas I will try it

Answer (score 2):

You can create tabs using react js

**React js tabs demo:**

```js
var tabData = [
  { name: 'Tab 1', isActive: true },
  { name: 'Tab 2', isActive: false },
  { name: 'Tab 3', isActive: false }
];
var Tabs = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
        {tabData.map(function(tab){
          return (
            <Tab data={tab} isActive={this.props.activeTab === tab} handleClick={this.props.changeTab.bind(this,tab)} />
          );
        }.bind(this))}      
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
var Tab = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <li onClick={this.props.handleClick} className={this.props.isActive ? "active" : null}>
        <a href="#">{this.props.data.name}</a>
      </li>
    );
  }
});
var Content = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.activeTab.name === 'Tab 1' ? 
        <section className="panel panel-success">
          <h2 className="panel-heading">Content 1</h2>
          <p className="panel-body">Bacon ham hock kevin boudin rump leberkas. Spare ribs kielbasa shankle hamburger tongue jerky pork chop bresaola. Shoulder pork belly short loin strip steak prosciutto frankfurter. Beef kevin t-bone venison pork belly meatball chuck short loin bresaola doner picanha. Cupim short ribs short loin brisket bacon rump porchetta venison t-bone drumstick pork chop hamburger meatball. Pork loin frankfurter shankle pork picanha pastrami. Pork loin pancetta venison short loin frankfurter.</p>
          <p className="panel-body">Shoulder doner swine ball tip venison porchetta. Capicola beef meatball, tri-tip strip steak kevin jowl cupim venison. Tongue fatback ribeye leberkas biltong t-bone. Pancetta frankfurter meatloaf, pig t-bone picanha ham fatback chicken drumstick short loin cupim short ribs cow. Beef short ribs ribeye meatball filet mignon andouille frankfurter swine turducken bresaola spare ribs cupim picanha cow. Drumstick tenderloin ham hock shoulder ground round, beef strip steak flank. Salami rump beef ground round.</p>
         </section>
        :null} 
        {this.props.activeTab.name === 'Tab 2' ? 
        <section className="panel panel-warning">
          <h2 className="panel-heading">Content 2</h2>
          <p className="panel-body">Atlantic herring jellynose fish Siamese fighting fish pollock: cobbler snakehead sea raven! Freshwater shark sergeant major clingfish sweeper galjoen fish mudfish longjaw mudsucker. Death Valley pupfish pomfret electric ray zingel African glass catfish squawfish yellowtail snapper grunt sculpin.</p>
          <p className="panel-body">Pike ribbon sawtail fish common tunny, yellowfin grouper pearl perch mooneye three-toothed puffer Bengal danio. Black sea bass turbot, "madtom swallower northern anchovy Red whalefish; Redhorse sucker." Filefish yellow jack Japanese eel longfin smelt stargazer saury yellow weaver flounder white croaker pink salmon. Pacific herring, whiff pink salmon jack wallago! Yellow jack alfonsino pike chubsucker, yellowtail collared dogfish rivuline tailor eelblenny silver carp; smalltooth sawfish--sea chub powen giant gourami. Inconnu false trevally pompano, half-gill roundhead black dragonfish damselfish: king of herring.</p>
        </section>
        :null} 
        {this.props.activeTab.name === 'Tab 3' ? 
        <section className="panel panel-danger">
          <h2 className="panel-heading">Content 3</h2>
          <p className="panel-body">Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea. Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke.</p>
          <p className="panel-body">Beetroot water spinach okra water chestnut ricebean pea catsear courgette summer purslane. Water spinach arugula pea tatsoi aubergine spring onion bush tomato kale radicchio turnip chicory salsify pea sprouts fava bean. Dandelion zucchini burdock yarrow chickpea dandelion sorrel courgette turnip greens tigernut soybean radish artichoke wattle seed endive groundnut broccoli arugula.</p>
        </section>
        :null} 
      </div>
    );
  }
});
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      activeTab: tabData[0]
    }
  }, 
  handleClick: function(tab) {
    this.setState({activeTab: tab});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Tabs activeTab={this.state.activeTab} changeTab={this.handleClick} />
        <Content activeTab={this.state.activeTab} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
#app {
  height: 100vh;
}
.nav {
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  background: #333;
}
.is-visible {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
section {
  margin: 20px;
}
h2, p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/react.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app"></div>
```