# How to make a <button> in Bootstrap look like a normal link in nav-tabs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working in (formerly Twitter) Bootstrap 2 and I wanted to style buttons as though they were normal links. Not just any normal links, though; these are going in a `<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">` container. The markup will end up like this:

```
<form action="..." method="post">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <!-- Navigation for the form -->
    <div class="span3">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
        <li><button type="submit" name="op" value="Link 1">Link 1</button></li>
        <li><button type="submit" name="op" value="Link 2">Link 2</button></li>
        <!-- ... -->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- The actual form -->
    <div class="span9">
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Does Bootstrap have any way to make these `<button>`s look like they were actually `<a>`s?

Comment: Here are all the classes you can put on `<button>` elements: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons

Comment: Why not using <a> instead <button>?

Comment: Because I need to maintain the form state that's in the rest of the form. Mainly that means a form session ID, and making it actually a link would mean switching the whole form to GET and putting that data in the `href`. So basically I either have to dramatically change how my form operates or change the presentation. This question is my attempt to find out how easy it is to change the presentation.

Comment: @VitorVenturin my use case: the default tab has a textarea for inputting markdown. Tab 2 has the HTML preview. So I don't want Tab 2 to have an URL that opens it by default. If I use links, then users can middle click and see a meaningless address location on hover. Button prevents that.

Answer (score 236):

[**As noted in the official documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options), simply apply the class(es) `btn btn-link`:

```
<!-- Deemphasize a button by making it look like a link while maintaining button behavior -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
```

For example, with the code you have provided:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<form action="..." method="post">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <!-- Navigation for the form -->
    <div class="span3">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
        <li>
          <button class="btn btn-link" role="link" type="submit" name="op" value="Link 1">Link 1</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <button class="btn btn-link" role="link" type="submit" name="op" value="Link 2">Link 2</button>
        </li>
        <!-- ... -->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- The actual form -->
    <div class="span9">
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That does make it no longer look like a button. However, it is not displaying as I want it to within the ul.nav-stacked markup. The CSS for that markup seems to only work with `<a>` tags...

Comment: Shows differently than links.

Comment: in Bootstrap 3, buttons styled like this *look* like links but they have too much padding around them which messes up the layout. BUT you can fix that by adding a small amount of CSS (see @mcNux answer below)

Answer (score 20):

Just make regular link look like button :)

```
<a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-success btn-large">Click here!</a>
```

"role" inside a href code makes it look like button, ofc you can add more variables such as class.

Comment: This is useful but does not answer the question asked.

Comment: `I wanted to style buttons as though they were normal links` this is the opposite :S

Comment: `role` attribute is not a valid attribute for the `a` element. (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Comment: This is the opposite of what is being asked

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the button text in this case is actually styled like a link which is not good (e.g. if you use "$link-decoration: underline !default;" in your _variables.scss). This should be probably noted by developers - perhaps this is not what they wanted to achieve. The link should be styled COMPLETELY as a button.

Comment: After a bit of experimenting I came to using the ".stretched-link" style to combine a link with a button without applying link styles to the button text.

<button style="transform: rotate(0);" role="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Button text
<a href="#mylink" class="stretched-link"></a>
</button>

Pay attention to: style="transform: rotate(0);"

More details here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/stretched-link/#identifying-the-containing-block

Answer (score 16):

Just add remove_button_css as class to your button tag. You can verify the code for Link 1

```
.remove_button_css { 
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px; 
  border: 0px; 
  box-sizing: none; 
  background-color: transparent; 
}
```

[image]

**Extra Styles Edit**

Add `color: #337ab7;` and `:hover` and `:focus` to match OOTB (bootstrap3)

```
.remove_button_css:focus,
.remove_button_css:hover {
    color: #23527c;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Added `:hover` and `:focus` for a closer match with bootstrap3.

Answer (score 13):

In bootstrap 3, this works well for me:

```
.btn-link.btn-anchor {
    outline: none !important;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Used like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-link btn-anchor">My Button</button>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/byuz9so8/5/)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Bootstrap 3 .btn-link doesn't cut it and you just have to add a class on your own.

Comment: YES this works perfectly. Instantaneously my BS3 form layout has the correct vertical spacing between the rows. Excellent.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was  looking for.

Comment: In recent versions of Bootstrap (I'm using 5.2) you can do this just using Bootstrap classes (no need for the CSS part of the answer): `<button type="button" class="btn btn-link p-0 border-0 align-baseline">My Button</button> `

Answer (score 2):

Just get rid of the background color, borders and add hover effects. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yPU29/

```
<form action="..." method="post">
<div class="row-fluid">
<!-- Navigation for the form -->
<div class="span3">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <li><button type="submit" name="op" value="Link 1" class="button-link">Link 1</button></li>
    <li><button type="submit" name="op" value="Link 2" class="button-link">Link 2</button></li>
    <!-- ... -->
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- The actual form -->
<div class="span9">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.button-link {
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
}

.button-link:hover {
color: blue;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: I added a few more CSS elements to make it look exactly like a dropdown link. In total: .button-link {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
}

.button-link:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all examples, posted here, but they do not work without extra CSS. Try this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Google</button></a>
```

Works perfectly without any extra CSS.

Comment: This isn't valid HTML. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393863/496046

Answer (score 0):

In react-bootstrap this looks like

```
<Button
  variant="link"
  className="text-start shadow-none"
  onClick={onClick}
>
  My Button
</Button
```

The `shadow-none` gets rid of the highlighting after click. The `text-start` stops the text from centering.

Answer (score -1):

here is a example:

```
<form method="POST" > 
  <button type="submit" class=" linkish  my-1 far fa-thumbs-down fa-2x">  </button>

  <button type="submit" class=" linkish  btn btn-primary">click me</button>

</form>
```

and css style :

```
.linkish {
    background-color: transparent!important;
    border: 0!important;
    color: blue!important;
    cursor: pointer!important;
    display: inline!important;
    margin: 0!important;
    outline: none!important;
    padding: 0!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
}



.linkish:hover {
 text-decoration: underline!important;
}
```

this is just example , and change it based on your case / requirements.

i hope this helpful .