# Make button a clickable link in bootstrap form?

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I feel like I've  exhausted every option from the standard a href approach on down the list. Nothing has worked so far. What is the correct way to treat a bootstrap button like a link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a <button> in Bootstrap look like a normal link in nav-tabs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981949/how-to-make-a-button-in-bootstrap-look-like-a-normal-link-in-nav-tabs)

Answer (score 2):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to display link as a button (the other way around)
https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/42/

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="btn btn-success">Click here</a>
```