# icon as the main button in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My problem is quite simple. I just want the icon to be the button. No borders. I've tried button_to but somehow it produces the icon inside the button. I've also tried link_to and it looks good but then this is gonna be used to submit a form. It's quite simple but somehow I can't get the behavior that i want.

Here are my attempts at this:

```
= button_tag(type: 'submit') do
  i class="fa fa-arrow-right arrow-enter"

= f.submit "", class: 'fa fa-arrow-right arrow-enter',id: 'user_sign_form_submit'

= link_to "", some_path(), class: 'fa fa-arrow-right arrow-enter'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: @joaumg yes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Bootstrap, you can use (untested):

```
= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-link') do
  i class="fa fa-arrow-right arrow-enter"
```

More info of the `btn-link` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981949/how-to-make-a-button-in-bootstrap-look-like-a-normal-link-in-nav-tabs) and [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options)

Comment: do you have any idea how you saved me tonight?! :D up you go my good sir/maam