# VS 2012 publishing a webside 2 big problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, ftp, filezilla

I am new to coding and everytime I ask a question I feel like stupid because I mostly am unfamiliar with most known things in this "industry" so I will sum up the whole situation fastly.

I learned how to code html css and js, I learned how to use VS 2012 asp.net mvc 4 and finally I made a webside for a student club I am into. Hosting is provided by our school and they only gave me ftp user name and password, I dont know which hosting firm is it or what is going on and so on, I got Filezilla to delete and unpublish the old webside, and I didnt know a proper way to publish asp.net websides through filezilla so I used VS 2012 publish tool.

---

I choosed FTP as publish method because I had ftp user name... I choosed relase as configuration and thats it ( I didnt open options here ) finally I could push on publish...

I faced 2 main problems so I couldnt publish

Problems I faced were;

1) While I was trying to publish I got an error like 
**" Validation (HTML5): Element 'a' must not be nested within element 'a button' "** 
I was trying to make a nav with sub items on it, It worked while I was trying it on local host I saw similar problems spoken out here on VS 2010 I tried to make exstensions to VS didnt work out

Anyway I deleted that part from the project and I tried publishing again.

2)It worked out perfect it seemed like no problem occoured. But when I try to open the webside **it was saying I had no permisson to view.**

I hope I didnt write any off topic staff here just try to tell you my problems so maybe someone can get help like I did from prior topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> " Validation (HTML5): Element 'a' must not be nested within element 'a
>   button' "

You cannot have one anchor tag inside another anchor tag. If you have it that will cause you the problem.

Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5) to find out valid elements which can be nested inside an Anchor tag.

> I had no permisson to view.

You need to give proper read/write permissions for the ApplicationPool Identity on the folder structure you have for your website. Or else IIS Apppool will not be able to get the files and execute them.

[Give permissions to AppPool Identity for a particular folder/file.](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) That resource will guide you one how to give you permissions to Application Pool Identity.

Alternatively  you can give [permissions from FileZilla](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-change-file-permissions-using-filezilla-on-.html) itself. Simply right click the application root folder and select permissions. Then you can specify permissions from client side itself. But in most of the production cases, we have to add app pool user to the folder/file permissions list manually. But definitely give a try with FileZilla.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :) first link really helped now I can revise my work according to what I can and cant to in a webside :) 

For the second one I am still having the problem, I used the FileZilla method but permissions are just like the link you sent.
Maybe asp.net is not supported by school's host do you think is it possible. Because when I delete every file through FileZilla it also says I have no permission. Or maybe I should use the first AppPool identity permissions link?

Comment: @user3288481, There are many steps in hosting a ASP.NEt MVC application in IIS. You need to have proper App Pool configuration, you need to make sure IIS is enabled for ASP.Net. Then you need to give proper permissions for IIS user on the folder etc. I would suggest you to do some more research on hosting asp.net application, you can check out some of these tutorials - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment