# The element label must not appear as a descendant of the a element

Tags: html, validation, label, href

Everthing seems to work fine, but when I validate my xml I get an error `The element label must not appear as a descendant of the a element.` Something similar was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837102/the-element-a-must-not-appear-as-a-descendant-of-the-button-element), but that did squat for me. If I put the `label` out of `a` then only the `icon` next to the label works as a link, but I want the whole thing.

My current code

```
<a href="#">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
   <label class="iconLabel">Settings</label>
</a>
```

I've tried puting `span`and `label` inside `div`, but nothing changed

Comment: Inside which div? I didn't understand this point.

Comment: Act of desperation, I just encapsulated `span` and `label` in empty `div` hoping to solve the problem

Comment: ok, what happens if you change label for span but keep this in the same place using this "iconLabel" class, this should work, or not?

Comment: Works, I feel silly now, I was just too fixated on trying to make the label work >< Can you add the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `label` for `span`, but keep this in the same place, keeping the class "iconLabel", this should work.

Code:

```
<a href="#">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
   <span class="iconLabel">Settings</span>
</a>
```