# Link button doesn't validate

Tags: html, validation, button, hyperlink

I have created a link button and it doesn't validate. I don't know why? I have searched for tips and everyone says it should work but it keeps showing the error?

```
<a href="home.html"><button id="english">English</button></a>
```

[Image of validation errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewjWv.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I nest a <button> element inside an <a> using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5)

Comment: it's a very weird question and asked surely the wrong way. if you need to understand the exact warning you've got from validation you could also check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837102/the-element-button-must-not-appear-as-a-descendant-of-the-a-element