# Anchor around button automatically redirecting

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, anchor

I am trying to make a lightbox appear when a button is pushed. Problem is, when the anchor is around the button (like in the code below), it automatically redirects to "mywebsite.com/myimage.jpg". However when the anchor is inside, only clicking the text will pop the lightbox. Here is the code:

```
<a href="myimage.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Title!" style="color:white" class="lightbox">
    <div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block" style="background:red">Button Text!</button>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: so what do you want to happen?

Comment: I want a button to pop up the lightbox

Comment: `Problem is, when the href is around the button (like in the code below)`...can you finish this sentence? Whats the problem?

Comment: `<button>` within `<a>` is invalid. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6393863/2476884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors and buttons have two different intended purposes, though Bootstrap allows you to style either as a button. Pick one. Using both is just bad practice.

```
<a href="myimage.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Title!" 
    class="lightbox btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block my-button-class">Button Text!</a>
```

The `.btn-danger` variant gets you the white-on-red scheme you seem to be going for. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options.

If this doesn't solve your problem you'll need to be more clear about which lightbox plugin you're using and what properties it's looking for.