# Trying to put a button into a link

Tags: html, button

I have a clickable span, which has a button in it. I want the span to go to one href and the button to another. Here is the code I currently have:

```
<script>
function deleteAlbum(url) {
    var txt;
    var r = confirm("Do you really want to delete this album?");
    if (r == true) {
        window.location.href = url;
    } 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>    

<a href='gallery.php?album=16022015NewTest'>
    <span class='album'>
        <p>New Test</p>
        <p>16/02/2015</p>
        <button class='delete' onClick=deleteAlbum('gallery.php?delete_album=16022015NewTest')>
            Delete Album
        </button>
    </span>
</a>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: please post your css. also, by clickable span, do you mean the `a` tag? Seems odd to have a clickable element inside a `a` tag, you'll need to prevent the defautl action of the 'a' tag when a better approach would be to wrap just the `p` tags in the `a`

Comment: This wouldn't work, the entirety of the span (essentially a box) is the link, making just the p elements the link would defeat the whole purpose of the exercise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to read up on [event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) - the quirksmode explanation in that answer is very nice.

Here's one possible fix for your example:

```
<script>
function gotoAlbum(albumId) {
  window.location.href="gallery.php?album="+albumId;
}

function deleteAlbum(e, url) {
  var r = confirm("Do you really want to delete this album?");
  if (r == true) {
    window.location.href = url;
  } 
 e.stopPropagation();
}
</script>    


<span class='album' onClick="gotoAlbum('16022015NewTest');" >
  <p>New Test</p>
  <p>16/02/2015</p>
  <button class='delete' onClick="deleteAlbum(event, 'gallery.php?delete_album=16022015NewTest');">Delete Album</button>
</span>
```

Aside: as the other comments mention, a button inside an anchor is odd - it's not compliant HTML5 - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5)

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Don't put `<button>` inside `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

According to atmd's comment restructure your html: **Don't put `button` inside `a`**. To be html conform use quotes for attribute values:

```
<div class="album">
    <a href="gallery.php?album=16022015NewTest">
        <p>New Test</p>
        <p>16/02/2015</p>
    </a>
    <button class="delete" onClick="deleteAlbum('gallery.php?delete_album=16022015NewTest')">Delete Album</button>
</div>
```

So the `a` tag does not include the `button` tag. It is also a good idea not to have block elements inside inline elements. The `span` tag has already been changed to a `div` tag. You might also change the `p` tags to `span`. Then the html looks like this:

```
<div class="album">
    <a href="gallery.php?album=16022015NewTest">
        <span>New Test</span>
        <span>16/02/2015</span>
    </a>
    <button class="delete" onClick="deleteAlbum('gallery.php?delete_album=16022015NewTest')">Delete Album</button>
</div>
```