# Is this html valid (button link)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, href

I require a button to be a link to a new window.

My code works in all desktop browsers I have tried so far, however when I run it through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) I get the error below;

> The element button must not appear as a descendant of the a element.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">contact</button></a>
```

If somebody could tell me how it should look in order to be sematically correct I would be very grateful.

Note I am using the bootstrap framework hence the btn class.

Comment: Why put a button within a link when you can use bootstrap to style the link itself to look like a button? http://www.bootply.com/3IjtTsDtgr

Comment: Yes this is invalid. Button inside link and link inside button are both incorrect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already answered your question. The HTML is invalid.

Just give the `a` element the classes that the `button` element had:

```
<a class="btn btn-success" href="http://www.example.com">contact</a>
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5fms67pw/) - the appearance is the same.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need a `<button>` element, so just remove it and move class argument into `<a>` element:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" class="btn btn-success">contact</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not valid.

The HTML should look like:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">contact</a>
```

(With whatever classes you want to add). You can then style the link to look however you like.

You should use a button *instead* of a link if you want to submit a form or have a non-link that triggers JavaScript.