# Centering text within a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning Front end development and I'm trying to code my first site using bootstrap. I got stuck on a pretty simple thing I guess. 
How do I center a text within a button ?

This is the button, the default one using an "a" tag.

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-work" href="#">Check my work</a>
```

and gave it a width and a height and the text remains stuck on the top..

```
.btn-work {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I'm also trying to align the button to the center of the container and I can't figure that out either.

Thanks !

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To center the text within the button. Use this code.

```
.btn-work{ text-align: center; }
```

To center the button, use a parent div to align it to center.

CSS:

```
 div.parentElement{text-align: center;}
 .btn-work{ display: inline-block; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parentElement">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-work" href="#">Check my work</a>
</div>
```

Full CSS:

```
div.parentElement{text-align: center;}

.btn-work {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I just registered on stackoverflow and honestly I wasn't expecting that I'll get an answer this quick.

Comment: Hey @OvidiuG You wanted to center the text inside the button right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I got it centered now but seems like I have another problem. Because that I have a button made by a 2px border the button is not centered properly. I hope I'll find the answer on google :D

Comment: You can search for box-model term in google. I have quick code for you to work.

    .btn-work{box-sizing: border-box;}

Comment: `padding: 0` fixed it for me

Answer (score 7):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/8pL75yq4/)

Use

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

in your `CSS` for  `.btn-work`.

So, the complete CSS would be like

```
.btn-work {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And, the output of the above one be like

[image]

Comment: also text-align:center to align to center of the available width

Comment: No need for that @radiant. Its already specified there in bootstrap css ->`.btn`

Answer (score 6):

I just discover it.

Just use

`line-height: 0px;`

in your button CSS.

Now, your CSS will look like this`:-`

`.btn{ line-height: 0px;}`

Comment: actually, the only solution that worked out for me, thanks

Comment: The same for me.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes using `text-align: center` does not work, even on the parent element.

You may need:

```
padding: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
button {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

On the button itself, you can make a class for all the buttons and apply the css

Answer (score 0):

In here you make a link as a button. You can make a button inside  tag.

```
 <a class="btn btn-default btn-work" href=""><input type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-work" value="Check my work"/></a>
```

Comment: It might work but it would not be a valid markup. "Element 'button' must not be nested within element 'a button'. Refer this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5