# Text inside button not aligning

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to center the text in a button but somehow `text-align: center;` is not working.

Anyone got an idea?

HTML:

```html
<div class="buttons">

    <div id="base">
      <button class='button' data-next="games" data-parent="base">Games</button>
      <button class='button' data-next="work" data-parent="base">Work</button>
    </div>

    <div id="games" class="hidden">
      <button class='button' data-next="games-heavy" data-parent="games" final-answer="games-heavy1">Heavy Games</button>
      <button class='button' data-next="games-light" data-parent="games" final-answer="games-light1">Light Games</button>
    </div>

    <div id="work" class="hidden">
      <button class='button' data-next="work-heavy" data-parent="work" final-answer="work-heavy1">Heavy Apps</button>
      <button class='button' data-next="work-light" data-parent="work" final-answer="work-light1">Light Apps</button>
    </div>

    <p id="games-heavy" class="hidden">Heavy games</p>
    <p id="games-light" class="hidden">Light games</p>
    <p id="work-heavy" class="hidden">Heavy applications</p>
    <p id="work-light" class="hidden">Light applications</p>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.buttons {
    border: none;
    width: 99%;
}

.button {
    margin: .3rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: .9rem;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what it looks like for you? Seems to be centering for me

Comment: Did you notice that all the 'button' classes in the html tags are in single quotes whereas everything else is in double quotes?

Comment: @Still_learning: That doesn't matter. Either single or double quotes will work.

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk I know but it's good practice to be consistent within the same file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Centering text within a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188383/centering-text-within-a-button)

Comment: No, it does note since that link does not use flex. I've found the answer, provided the answer also in the answer column. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `justify-content: center` instead of `text-align: center` and also remove `flex-direction` css

```css
.buttons {
    border: none;
    width: 99%;
}

.button {
    margin: .3rem;
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: .9rem;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">

            <div id="base">
              <button class='button' data-next="games" data-parent="base">Games</button>
              <button class='button' data-next="work" data-parent="base">Work</button>
            </div>

            <div id="games" class="hidden">
              <button class='button' data-next="games-heavy" data-parent="games" final-answer="games-heavy1">Heavy Games</button>
              <button class='button' data-next="games-light" data-parent="games" final-answer="games-light1">Light Games</button>
            </div>

            <div id="work" class="hidden">
              <button class='button' data-next="work-heavy" data-parent="work" final-answer="work-heavy1">Heavy Apps</button>
              <button class='button' data-next="work-light" data-parent="work" final-answer="work-light1">Light Apps</button>
            </div>

            <p id="games-heavy" class="hidden">Heavy games</p>
            <p id="games-light" class="hidden">Light games</p>
            <p id="work-heavy" class="hidden">Heavy applications</p>
            <p id="work-light" class="hidden">Light applications</p>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`align-items:center` because you are using flex.

Answer (score 1):

Remove display:flex and flex-direction from your css.

```css
.buttons {
    border: none;
    width: 99%;
  }

  .button {
    margin: .2rem;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: .9rem;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="buttons">

  <div id="base">
    <button class='button' data-next="games" data-parent="base">Games</button>
    <button class='button' data-next="work" data-parent="base">Work</button>
  </div>

  <div id="games" class="hidden">
    <button class='button' data-next="games-heavy" data-parent="games" final-answer="games-heavy1">Heavy Games</button>
    <button class='button' data-next="games-light" data-parent="games" final-answer="games-light1">Light Games</button>
  </div>

  <div id="work" class="hidden">
    <button class='button' data-next="work-heavy" data-parent="work" final-answer="work-heavy1">Heavy Apps</button>
    <button class='button' data-next="work-light" data-parent="work" final-answer="work-light1">Light Apps</button>
  </div>

  <p id="games-heavy" class="hidden">Heavy games</p>
  <p id="games-light" class="hidden">Light games</p>
  <p id="work-heavy" class="hidden">Heavy applications</p>
  <p id="work-light" class="hidden">Light applications</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got the answer.

I was setting my buttons individually to:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Which also set the alignment of the text and did not accept the `text-align: center;` because of it.

I moved

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

to the  `<div class="buttons">` which owned all the buttons and it worked.

Sorry all!