# Button with Icon in tabview

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabview

i use primefaces 5.2 and i want to add a commandbutton to a tab inside a tabview. 
Code to test:

```
<p:tabView>
<p:tab>
    <f:facet name="title">
        <h:outputText value="Error Log"/>
        <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-refresh" id="fetcherror" update="form:msg errorlogpane" style="margin-left: 12px;"/>
    </f:facet>

    <p:scrollPanel id="errorlogpane" style="height: 300px">
    </p:scrollPanel>
</p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

I want a label and at the right a button inside the tab to reload the tab content. The Button does not need any text, just an icon to show the functionality. 
But if i deploy the above code the icon is not correct in place as you can see in the following picture

[image: here]

The Resulting html code is:

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true">
    <a href="#form:j_idt29:j_idt30" tabindex="-1">Error Log<button id="form:j_idt29:fetcherror" name="form:j_idt29:fetcherror" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" style="margin-left: 12px;" type="submit">
        <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c fa fa-refresh"></span>
        <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">ui-button</span>
    </button>
    </a>
</li>
```

What is the problem with this tab design? How can i fix it? Any suggestion helps :)

Comment: AFAIK, this will never work.  The resulting output will be two nested `<a href>`.  As a workaround you could put the refresh button inside the tab not in the tab `title`.

Comment: Hm as  far as  i can see  there are no 2 hrefs. The second code shows the resulting HTML.... Also the button is working  well and as expected. Only the icon looks deranged...

Comment: Sorry, I should have said [nesting a `<button>` inside a `<a href>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5).  I'm surprised it is working.