# Button to Download a pdf file

Tags: html, pdf, button, download

I have a HTML button and I want it to download the pdf file by pressing it.
Thank you

```
       <div class="columns download">
          <p>
             <a href="images/Portfolio.pdf" class="button"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Download CV</a>
          </p>
       </div>
```

Comment: try this .. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: and also fyi,  the browser by default, downloads the pdf file and if you provide the `<a>` link, and if the pdf viewer is enabled by default the browser will show the pdf.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: When I press the Button it goes to a new page with the pdf online.
I don't want that!
I want to download it...

Answer (score 7):

The way to do that is to embed the button inside the a tag link.

```
<a href="./abcf32x.pdf" download="How-to-download-file.pdf">
    <button>Download File</button>
</a>
```

Comment: A button inside an anchor is invalid HTML5: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393863/7903952

Comment: At this moment it only fails when the button is inside a <form> Thus operationally it is not considered invalid everywhere

Answer (score 6):

```
 <div class="columns download">
          <p>
             <a href="images/Portfolio.pdf" class="button" download><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Download CV</a>
          </p>
       </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<p>    
    <a href="files/document.pdf" class="button">
       <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
          Download CV
    </a>
</p>
```