# why <a href> tag doesn't work inside a form

Tags: html

why a href tag in html does not work inside a form? I am trying to use that for my jsp page transitions, but it really doesn't work.

here's my code:

```html
    <form method="GET" action="Controller">
          <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
          <a href="/Controller?action=add"><input 
             type="button" value="Add"/></a>
    </form>
```

what is the problem why it's not working?

Comment: Links will not submit the form. You need an `<input type="submit">` or `<button type="submit">` for that.

Comment: Are you attempting to submit the form using the link?

Comment: this code looks just wrong. Are you sure you understand the basics of html forms? What is your desired behaviour?

Comment: Your entire concept is wrong. Please refer to (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) to learn the basics to <form>.

Answer (score 3):

You can't wrap an anchor in a button, as they both do something when clicked - it's not valid HTML either. Try:

```html
<form method="GET" action="/Controller?action=add">
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  <input type="button" value="Add" />
</form>
```

See if that works, but don't wrap a button in an anchor :)

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5) for other elements which can't be wrapped in `<a>` tags.

Comment: +1 to the link referenced. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5#comment128527977_46868428 I could make my following form work though html5-spec-wise the button inside link is not correct: 
`<form action='/my_path' method='POST'><button type="button" class="button-primary save-btn">Save</button><a href="/contents"><button type="button" class="button-primary cancel-save-btn">Cancel</button></a></form>`. Note: without `type="button"` on the button inside `<a>`, link-button click will submit the form.