Control does not reached the Http POST method in the controller when form is submitted from a view in my ASP.NET Core MVC web app
I am learning ASP.NET Core MVC framework (.NET 8) by building a sample project: Following are the code files-

In the Program.cs file I have the following services registered:

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options=>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

//registering the Authetication Services with COOKIE Autheticaition scheme
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(option =>
    {
        option.LoginPath = "/UserAccess/Login";
        option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);

    });

//some line of code then..

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");



Model: UserLogin.cs


    public class UserLogin
    {
        public string? Username { get; set; }        
        public string? Password { get; set; }
        public bool KeepLoggedIn { get; set; } = false;      
    }



Controller : UserAccessController.cs I have the below IActionResult methods one for GET and one for POST:

public class UserAccessController : Controller
{

public IActionResult Login()
{    
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserLogin usrLogin)
{  
   //will perform password verification and generate Httpcontext
      return View();
}


View: Login.cshtml

@model UserLogin

<h1>User Entry according to Role</h1>

<form method="post" asp-controller="UserAccess" asp-action="Login">
    <div class="mt-2 mb-3">
        <input asp-for="Username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <a class="col-3 ms-3 btn btn-outline-primary" role="button" >Log In</a>
        <a href="#" class="col-6 ms-2 text-decoration-none text-success">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
</form>

In the Home view I have the following button, when clicked goes to the UserAccessController and display the view Login.cshtml.
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" role="button" asp-controller="UserAccess" asp-action="Login">Click to Login</a>

My problem is when I click the Log In button from the Login.cshtml view the IActionResult of the [Httppost] does not get hit and the control does not go there. Only the method for GET gets hit when I initially load the form. Thus I am not able to perform the Login functionality. Thank you in Advance.
Tried changing the UserLogin-ViewModel to UserLogin-Model. Since I thought that it has something to do with Model Validation.

Use <button> element instead of <a>. <button class="col-3 ms-3 btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" >Log In</button>

@YongShun The issue is resolved now. Thank you for your help. But I am still wondering why the  tag is not working.

@BaluS a tag is not supposed to submit forms. Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117563/why-a-href-tag-doesnt-work-inside-a-form

You can add a button type="submit" attribute to the Log In button to ensure that the form is submitted when the button is clicked.
<button type="submit" class="col-3 ms-3 btn btn-outline-primary">Log In</button>



If you want to trigger form submission via the <a> tag, you can do so by adding an id attribute to the  tag. Then, use JavaScript's event listener to capture the click event and manually submit the form when the "Log In" link is clicked. Here is an example you can refer to:
@model UserLogin

<h1>User Entry according to Role</h1>

<form id="loginForm" method="post" asp-controller="UserAccess" asp-action="Login">
    <div class="mt-2 mb-3">
        <input asp-for="Username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
       
        <a id="loginLink" class="col-3 ms-3 btn btn-outline-primary" role="button">Log In</a>
        <a href="#" class="col-6 ms-2 text-decoration-none text-success">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
</form>

JS:
<script>
   
    const loginLink = document.getElementById("loginLink");
    const loginForm = document.getElementById("loginForm");

    loginLink.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
       
        event.preventDefault();
       
        loginForm.submit();
    });
</script>



