# Wrapping a react-router Link in an html button

Tags: html, reactjs, button, hyperlink, router

Using suggested method:
[This is the result: A link in the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN4AP.png),
[Code in between comment lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aykeJ.png)

I was wondering if there is a way to wrap a `Link` element from `'react-router'` in an HTML `button` tag using react.

I currently have `Link` components to navigate pages in my app, but I would like to map that functionality to my HTML buttons.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 278, accepted):

While this will render in a web browser, beware that:
⚠️[Nesting an html `button` in an html `a` (or vice-versa) **is not valid html**](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fdropbox.beausmith.com%2Fstatic-html%2Finvalid-button-anchor-markup.html) ⚠️.
If you want to keep your html semantic to screen readers, use another approach.

Do wrapping in the reverse way and you get the original button with the Link attached. No CSS changes required.

```
 <Link to="/dashboard">
     <button type="button">
          Click Me!
     </button>
 </Link>
```

Here button is HTML button. It is also applicable to the components imported from third party libraries like **Semantic-UI-React**.

```
 import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'
 ... 
 <Link to="/dashboard">
     <Button style={myStyle}>
        <p>Click Me!</p>
     </Button>
 </Link>
```

Comment: Thanks, simple and working, while css solution of @ChaseJames is not working. Maybe there something is missing. But I am using bootstrap; 
`import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';`.

Comment: When tabbing through the document you'll tab to the anchor, and then to the button separately. To avoid this, add tabindex="-1" to the Link element. The link will still be followed (at least in Firefox...) when the button is activated by pressing enter.

Comment: As you know, Link creates anchor tag `<a href="">` and anchor tag cannot contain button tag.

Comment: While this seems to work, it's semantically wrong (and invalid in HTML 5). See [Can I nest a <button> element inside an <a> using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5/6393863#6393863)

Comment: If you make your button disabled for example, clicking the button will still work. There's really no reason to use this hacky solution when compared to the `history.push` option

Comment: semantic-ui-react now supports component augmentation, you need to use as={ Link } prop on a regular semantic-ui-react Button component. Use the original props that you would of used in the Link component.

Comment: Burak, history prop is not available in version 6 of react-router-dom, for information you can see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70033584/7312335

Comment: Use <Button as={Link} to='/dashboard'> <p>Click me</p> </Button> for something cleaner. No extra HTML or react syntax to deal with and no chance for behavior weirdness with tabbing.

Answer (score 152):

## `LinkButton` component - a solution for React Router v4

First, a note about many other answers to this question.

### ⚠️ Nesting `<button>` and `<a>` is not valid html. ⚠️

Any answer here which suggests nesting a html `button` in a React Router `Link` component (or vice-versa) will render in a web browser, but it is not semantic, accessible, or valid html:

```
<a stuff-here><button>label text</button></a>
<button><a stuff-here>label text</a></button>
```

☝[Click to validate this markup with validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fdropbox.beausmith.com%2Fstatic-html%2Finvalid-button-anchor-markup.html) ☝

This can lead to layout/styling issues as buttons are not typically placed inside links.

---

### Using an html `<button>` tag with React Router `<Link>` component.

If you only want  an html `button` tag…

```
<button>label text</button>
```

…then, here's the right way to get a button that works like React Router’s `Link` component…

Use React Router’s [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC to pass these props to your component:

- `history`
- `location`
- `match`
- `staticContext`

---

## `LinkButton` component

Here’s a `LinkButton` component for you to copy/*pasta*:

```js
// file: /components/LinkButton.jsx
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

const LinkButton = (props) => {
  const {
    history,
    location,
    match,
    staticContext,
    to,
    onClick,
    // ⬆ filtering out props that `button` doesn’t know what to do with.
    ...rest
  } = props
  return (
    <button
      {...rest} // `children` is just another prop!
      onClick={(event) => {
        onClick && onClick(event)
        history.push(to)
      }}
    />
  )
}

LinkButton.propTypes = {
  to: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
}

export default withRouter(LinkButton)
```

Then import the component:

```js
import LinkButton from '/components/LinkButton'
```

Use the component:

```js
<LinkButton to='/path/to/page'>Push My Buttons!</LinkButton>
```

If you need an onClick method:

```js
<LinkButton
  to='/path/to/page'
  onClick={(event) => {
    console.log('custom event here!', event)
  }}
>Push My Buttons!</LinkButton>
```

**Update:** If you're looking for another fun option made available after the above was written, check out this [useRouter hook](https://usehooks.com/useRouter/).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. All other answers are, IMHO, hacks and can provide unexpected results. Thank you!

Comment: Would the usage of the component go inside the `<div> .. </div` element of `App.js` ?

Comment: @DJ2 - Yes, or in any other component you want to use it in.

Comment: Thanks for this! In my particular use case I imported a material-ui button with `import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';` and used that instead of `<button />` and it worked great.

Comment: it's really smarty to run `onClick` before making `history.push`. This way we could check `!event.isDefaultPrevented && history.push(...)` to make this work like [`<Link>` does](https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html#onclicke)

Comment: But you cannot use <a> features here like Ctrl+Click or seeing destination url in footer before clicking :( I am voting for @ChaseJames slution as the cleanest.

Comment: @Melounek - Hello there! If the goal is to have an `<a>` html tag visually styled to look like a "button", then yes @ChaseJames solution achieves this. The question above asks how to use a `<button>` html element, not an `<a>`.

Comment: withRouter is not available in version 6 react-router-dom now, those who are using latest version, they can work with hooks in functional components for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70033584/7312335

Comment: If you want semantic HTML you can do: `<button role="link">` for screen readers I believe.

Answer (score 64):

Why not just decorate link tag with the same css as a button.

```
<Link 
 className="btn btn-pink"
 role="button"
 to="/"
 onClick={this.handleClick()}
> 
 Button1
</Link>
```

Comment: I will keep this as a last resort mostly because I have the CSS done for all the buttons that I need but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Brilliant solution. For blueprint I do in this way:  <Link className={[Classes.BUTTON, Classes.MINIMAL, Classes.ICON + "-" + IconNames.PLUS].join(" ")} to={"/link"}>Link</Link>

Comment: You can't use enabled/disabled states on a fake button.

Comment: This is perhaps the best approach, because navigation typically should use link semantics, i.e., `<a/>` tags. It should be noted though that simply applying an existing CSS class designed for `<button/>` to an `<a/>` can lead to broken style. The reason is that these elements are fundamentally different in terms of CSS behavior, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66430085/1804173). In my case, I needed to refactor styles first to apply this solution.

Answer (score 44):

If you are using `react-router-dom` and `material-ui` you can use ...

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

<Button component={Link} to="/open-collective">
  Link
</Button>
```

You can read more [here](https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/#third-party-routing-library).

Comment: This solution will not work with TS since `to` prop on `Link` is mandatory.

Comment: My mistake was to import Link from `@material-ui/core` instead of `react-router-dom`

Comment: This worked for me in TS - no type errors.

Answer (score 30):

You can use `useHistory` **hook** since [react-router v5.1.0](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v5.1.0).

> The `useHistory` hook gives you access to the history instance that
> you may use to navigate.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function SomeComponent() {
  const { push } = useHistory()
  ...
  <button
    type="button"
    onClick={() => push('/some-link')}
  >
    Some link
  </button>
  ...
}
```

NOTE: be aware that this approach answers the question but is not accessible like @ziz194 says in their comment

> this is not accessible though, as the button will not be a  tag and thus it doesn't have link behaviours, like opening the link in a new page. It is also not optimal for screen readers.

CONCLUSION: The better way to handle this is to use an `<a>` tag and style it.

Comment: Can you push "some-link" to the function?

Comment: In 2020 this does not work for me. useHistory is null in my version of React

Comment: The import should read 'react-router-dom' not 'react-router'

Comment: Hey @Rafael, thank you. I changed it to `react-router-dom`

Comment: This is probably the most straightforward solution as of 2021.

Comment: this is not accessible though, as the button will not be a <a> tag and thus it doesn't have link behaviours, like opening the link in a new page. It is also not optimal for screen readers.

Comment: @ziz194, I just added your comment in my answer. Thanks for adding value.

Comment: In react-router-dom version 6, you are not able to use useHistory instead you can useNavigate.

Answer (score 20):

**Update for React Router version 6:**

The various answers here are like a timeline of react-router's evolution

Using the latest hooks from react-router v6, this can now be done easily with the `useNavigate` hook.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'      

function MyLinkButton() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  return (
      <button onClick={() => navigate("/home")}>
        Go Home
      </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: version 6 isn't available yet and this answer is confusing because of that.  

latest as of this comment is 5.2.0.

Comment: version 6 is currently available in beta and being used in some projects. Please see the Versions tab here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router

Comment: Using buttons for navigation is semantically incorrect, <a> is for navigation, not <button>

Answer (score 10):

With styled components this can be easily achieved

First Design a styled button

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const Button = styled.button`
  background: white;
  color:red;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
`
render(
    <Button as={Link} to="/home"> Text Goes Here </Button>
);
```

check [styled component's home](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics) for more

Answer (score 7):

I use Router and < Button/>. No < Link/>

```
<Button onClick={()=> {this.props.history.replace('/mypage')}}>
   HERE
</Button>
```

Comment: I think this should be the default solution, but perhaps some details are lost to me? _ANY_ component/node/element that support `onClick={ () => navigateTo(somePath) }` could use this approach. Whether using redux and `import {push} from 'connected-react-router'` or just `history.push` (or replace) like in your answer.

Comment: this solution is not accessible, you cannot open the link in a new page using this solution.

Answer (score 6):

⚠️ No, [Nesting an html `button` in an html `a` (or vice-versa) is not valid html](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fdropbox.beausmith.com%2Fstatic-html%2Finvalid-button-anchor-markup.html)

Comment: So I tried this, and what I got was a button with a small clickable link in the centre that served its function. However clicking anywhere else on the button but the direct link did nothing.

Comment: You can use CSS to style the button to ensure that it is sized correctly.  For example, setting it's `width` and `height`.

Comment: Oh I am aware. I am using CSS to give each button a background image, and set its behaviour to become slightly larger when hovered over. So its width x height are set to match the image size. I just need the WHOLE button to link to the path and to not just create a linkable line of text in the middle of the button. Also removing the text did nothing.

Comment: Can you screenshot the issue so I can see?

Comment: Sure. Uploaded to top of page

Comment: I see what you mean now.  We need to pass the `<button>`s `onClick` method to `<Link />`s.  Thinking of how best to do that.

Comment: What if you styled the `<button>`s child `<a>` tag to have the same height and width as it's parent?  `display: block;` would work on the `<a>` tag.

Comment: @JoseRivera Updated.

Comment: Tried to do that, but not sure what you meant.

Comment: How can I style a button's a tag?

Comment: You can use inline styles the same way for the button tag.  Or you can use one of the many "css in JS" libraries.  I prefer `styled-components`.  https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to play around with this some more later.

Comment: Should be recorded but wont display my upvote until my account reaches 15 rep. Will be sure to update it once it does!

Comment: It worked with your updated answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is not correct... You should wrap the button, not the link 

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking for a solution using **React 16.8+** (hooks) and React Router 5:

You can change the route using a button with the following code:

```
<button onClick={() => props.history.push("path")}>
```

**React Router provides** some props to your components, including the **push()** function on **history** which works pretty much like the < Link to='path' > element.

You don't need to wrap your components with the Higher Order Component "withRouter" to get access to those props.

Comment: This works fine for me; though I'm not sure what about this solution is specific to React 16.8+ or hooks.  I think you're in good shape with this so long as you employ `BrowserRouter` (based on the HTML history API) instead of `HashRouter`.

Comment: Navigation on click for non-Link elements is meh. You can't interact as you would with Link, so no "open in a new tab" features.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Button component={Link} to="/dashboard" type="button">
    Click Me!
</Button>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 1):

Many of the solutions have focused on complicating things.

Using withRouter is a really long solution for something as simple as a button that links to somewhere else in the App.

If you are going for S.P.A. (single page application), the easiest answer I have found is to use  with the button's equivalent className.

This ensures you are maintaining shared state / context without reloading your entire app as is done with

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'; // 14.6K (gzipped: 5.2 K)

// Where link.{something} is the imported data
<NavLink className={`bx--btn bx--btn--primary ${link.className}`} to={link.href} activeClassName={'active'}>
    {link.label}
</NavLink>

// Simplified version:
<NavLink className={'bx--btn bx--btn--primary'} to={'/myLocalPath'}>
    Button without using withRouter
</NavLink>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The hove style of the button is lost v_v.

Comment: Perhaps your hover styles are too restrictive? Are they assigned to button.myClassName? Remove button from the style selector. Or extend it in scss.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you utilize the `component` prop on the `Link` component. Using this, you can have effectively any component behave as an `a` component from the perspective of React Rotuer. For instance, you can create your own "Button" component and then utilize this.

```
const MyButton = () => {
    return <button>Do something with props, etc.</button>
}

<Link to="/somewhere" component={MyButton}>Potentially pass in text here</Link>
```

Comment: I agree, this is how it's meant to be used.
Personally I would write it this way though:
`<Link to="/somewhere" component={c => <button {...c} />}>Pass in text here</Link>`

Answer (score 1):

## Using `react-router-dom` and a function

In react, you can use `react-router-dom` by applying the `useHistory` call...

**- Firstly**

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
```

**- Secondly**
Inside your function...write a function to handle the button click

```
const handleButtonClick = () => {
    history.push('/YourPageLink')
  }
```

**- Lastly**

```
<button onClick={handleButtonClick} className="CSS">
   Button Text
</button>
```

Comment: in version 6,  useHistory is not applicable you can use useNavigate instead

Comment: Yes, useNavigate has been newly introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Just [useLinkClickHandler](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-link-click-handler) (for react-router version 6)

```
const ButtonLink = ({to, children, ...rest}) => {
  const handleClick = useLinkClickHandler(to);

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As I searched through answers everyone was talking about the old versions of react-router-dom, so this might be useful answer for those who want to use the hooks in functional components. As in the new version few hooks are changed and even the withRouter is not applicable you need to make a custom HOC.

we can achieve it through functional components you can use your button and then describe onClick event to trigger to the next page through useNavigate hook.

**React-Router-Dom version 6**

---

this is only possible in functional components as i am using hooks, if you want to use on class components then you can make hoc.

```
import {Link, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
function Home() {
you can pass your state like so:  navigate('/show',{state});
const toShowInfoPage=()=>{
navigate('/show');

  }


return(
<>


 /*you can use button as well or anything 
of your choice, but remember 
you have to pass the onClick event.
    */
 <a 
onClick={()=>{toShowInfoPage()}} 
style={{textDecoration:'none',
paddingRight:'20px',
color:'#187bcd',
cursor:'pointer'}}>


</>

)



}
```

To access useNavigate() with a class component you must either convert to a function component, or roll your own custom `withRouter` Higher Order Component to inject the "route props" like the `withRouter` HOC from `react-router-dom` v5.x did.

---

**This is just a general idea.**
if you want to useNavigate Here's an example custom `withRouter` HOC:

```
const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const params = useParams();
  // etc... other react-router-dom v6 hooks

  return (
    <WrappedComponent
      {...props}
      params={params}
      // etc...
    />
  );
};
```

And decorate the component with the new HOC.

```
export default withRouter(Post);
```

This will inject a `props` for the class component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `component` prop: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/component-reactcomponent

For example:

```
<Link to="/login" component={({ navigate}) => <button onClick={navigate}>Login</button>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

For `react-router-dom` `v5`
you can simply style the link itself to look like button:

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

<Link className="btn" to="/myurl">Submit</Link>
```

where `className="btn"` refers to the css class name, which makes it look like button.

Or you can define the following object:

```
export function ButtonLink(props) {
    const { as: Component, children, to, className } = props;
    return <Component className={className} to={to}>{children}</Component>
}
```

and then use it

```
import {ButtonLink} from "../../components/ButtonLink";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

<ButtonLink as={Link} to="/myUrl" className="btn">Submit</ButtonLink>
```

but you will still have to refer to css to make it look like button (`className="btn"`), so first approach is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

very simple - javascript part:

```
    <script>

    function gofor(link) {
        location.href = link;
    }

    </script>
```

and here the html part:

```
    <button onclick="gofor('link.html');">Click Me!</button>
```

Thats all.