# React Router v6, How to place <Link /> into a button and event handler

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm trying something like this:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
          // THIS HERE:
          onClick={<Link to="./Form"/>}
          >
          CLICK
        </Button>
```

I need: `<Button />`, with an onClick, to link me to './Form'. I am trying something like `<Button onClick={e => <Link to=".Form"/>}` and have tried every variation I can think of to make this work. Please someone help, and thanks.

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463263/wrapping-a-react-router-link-in-an-html-button

Comment: @cmgchess jeez... yes it does. Thank you. I'm in a boot camp and clawing my way through.

Comment: all the best! happy coding

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need to use the `component` [attribute](https://mui.com/api/button/#props) :

```
 <Button component={Link} to="./Form"
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
          >
          CLICK
        </Button>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. For <TextField /> I tried the same, "component={Link}" but this did not work. How can i make an onSubmit trigger a <Link /> change for a <TextField ?> ? Is there something I'm missing because I don't see this anywhere in MUI's docs or in React-Router v6's docs.

Comment: With onsubmit you will have to use a function which calls history.push() inside it. Textfield are not supposed to act like links, hence the functionality is not there. That is why the component attribute is not working

Comment: Ok, thank you so very much.

Comment: Sure. If it helps you please mark this as the accepted answer(green tick)

Answer (score 11):

You can use `useNavigate` hook from react router dom package.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import {Button} from "@mui/material"

export const TestComponent = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (
        <Button onClick={() => navigate('route here...')}>Click me!</Button>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way

```
  const history = useHistory();
  const navigateTo = () => history.push('/componentURL');//eg.history.push('/login');

  return (
   <div>
   <button onClick={navigateTo} type="button" />
   </div>
  );
```

Comment: Just do not forget to add `history` into your dependencies in case `react-router` will stop using in in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Just [useLinkClickHandler](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-link-click-handler)

```
const ButtonLink = ({to, children, ...rest}) => {
  const handleClick = useLinkClickHandler(to);

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```