# </Link> command doesn't routing. React.Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

[image: before pressing the button]

[image: After pressing the button]

First of all, I apologize for my bad English. As you can see in the pictures, when I press the login button, the url part changes but does not redirect to the page.

```
import React from "react";


import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css'
import logo from "./assets/resim.png"
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Forgot from './App_sifre.jsx'
import Home from './App_anasayfa.jsx'

function App() { 
  return (    
     <>
       <BrowserRouter>
       <Navbar/>
         <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element= {<Home />} />
          <Route path='/forgot' element= {<Forgot />} />
         </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
     </>
)}

export default function LoginPage () {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="bg">
       <div className="container" >
         <div className="card card-body mt-5 pb-5 shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded ">
           <h2 className="text-center text-info ">DMS Planlama Sistemi</h2>
           <div className="row mt-5 pb-5">
             <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 mb-5">
               <img src={logo} alt="login" className="img-fluid" />
             </div>
             <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
               <form>
                 <div className="form-group">
                   <label htmlFor="email">Kullanıcı Adı:</label>
                   <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Kullanıcı adınız" id="email" />
                 </div>
                 <div className="form-group">
                   <label htmlFor="pwd" style={{marginTop: '15px'}}>Şifre:</label>
                   <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="şifreniz" id="pwd" />
                 </div>
                 <div className="form-group form-check">
                   <label className="form-check-label">
                     <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" /> Beni Hatırla
                     <label><a href="şifremi unuttum/şifre yenileme.html" to="/sifre" style={{marginLeft: '30px'}}>Şifremi unuttum</a>
                     </label>
                   </label>
                 </div>
                   <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
                   <Link to="/forgot" >Login</Link>
                   </button>
               </form>
             </div>
           </div> 
         </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </BrowserRouter>
 )
 }
```

I checked the react files I imported but they are all in the same place, there is no way there is a mistake. What should I do to fix it?

[image: Files I use]

Comment: Not sure but maybe the fact that you have `<Link>` inside `<button>`?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463263/wrapping-a-react-router-link-in-an-html-button

Answer (score 0):

Using a  tag inside a  tag might not work as expected because the  tag has its own behavior for handling click events. Instead, you can use the useHistory hook from react-router-dom to navigate when the button is clicked.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const history = useHistory();
  const handleLoginClick = () => {

    history.push("/forgot");
  };

  <button
     type="button"
     className="btn btn-primary"
     onClick={handleLoginClick}
     >
      Login
      </button>
```