# How to navigate on path by button click in react router v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have this paths in react-router-dom:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
  <div>
  <Route exact path='/(index.html)?' component={Home}/> {/* app = home */}
  <Route  path='/register' component={Registration}/>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

everything is working fine, now anywhere in my components I want to change path by onClick, a code like this:

```
<button onClick={() => history.push('/the/path') }> change path </button>
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
...

class App extends React.Component {
  ...

  nextPath(path) {
    this.props.history.push(path);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.nextPath('/the/path') }>
        change path 
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is `withRouter` here ?

Comment: what if we have a stateless component

Comment: A stateless component will have `history` in props when wrapped in withRouter

Comment: withRouter is known as a HOC (https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) it is just another way of injecting functionality into your components, this is an easy way now in V4 to get access to the match and history objects

Comment: sadly the code is not working for me. I get the error that `withRouter` should not be used outside of `Router`

Answer (score 56):

If you're using the button only for navigation, you can replace it with `<Link />`<sup>1</sup> and apply a button style.

```
<Link to='/new/location/'>Click Me</Link>
```

Or you can use the `<NavLink />`<sup>2</sup>.

In case of using [Material UI](https://material-ui.com), you can use the following code:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

<Button component={Link} to="/new/location/">
  Click Me
</Button>
```

---

(1): `import {Link} from "react-router-dom";`
(2): `import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";`

Answer (score 45):

`react-router-dom` exports a hook called `useHistory`.
Just import it and use it in your component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default () => {
  const history = useHistory();
   
  return (
    <button onClick={() => history.push('/your/path')}>
      Click me
    </button>
  );
};
```

I'm using:

- "react": "^16.13.1"
- "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"

Check this post for more details: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/programmatically-navigate-react-router

Comment: What are the differences between useHistory and Link (wrap around the button)? Thanks

Comment: @HongLy the Link component renders a `<a>` tag, and you shouldn't put a button inside it. Here's a good explanation why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393863/7948938. In this case, it'd be better to use the Link component only, stylized to look like a button.

Comment: This is not a good answer because you lose out on accessibility.

Comment: @MalikBagwala tha accessibility problem you are mentioning is baked in the question. It asks for navigation on button clicks.

Answer (score 31):

in **react-router-dom version 6** use **useNavigate**

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
...
const navigate = useNavigate();
<Button
   onClick={() => navigate("/your-path-here")}>
click me
</Button>
```

do not forget to install from [mui.com](https://mui.com/) to use the `<Button></Button>` component

Answer (score 1):

in react-router-dom version 6, you can also use the Link component too. This is to back @Abey Bruck's answer

```
import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";
...

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Button as={Link} to={'/login'}>Login Page</Button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
const navigate = useNavigate();
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate(`/`);
  };
<Button variant="contained" onClick={submitHandler}>Home Page</Button>
```

Comment: you should add some documentation on the `useNavigate` hook and a link so that the user can check docs and learn than just code