# How can I get another component when I click a button?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react project In this have two components Home and Contact in Home I have button If I click that button I have to go Contact component. But in my Navbar I have only Home component so in output also I have only home page. So If I click the button I need to see Contact Component.

This is Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Navbarcollection() {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                            <ul className="navbar-nav">
                                <li className="nav-item active">
                                    <Link className='nav-link' to='/'>Home</Link>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './Navbar/Navbarcollection';
import Home from './Home/Home';
import Contact from './Contact/Contact';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/'><Home></Home></Route>
          <Route path='/contact'><Contact></Contact></Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Home.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div className='container pt-5 text-center'>
            <button className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is Contact.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Contact() {
    return (
        <div className='pt-5 text-center'>
            <h1>My name is Mark you can call me xxxxxxxxx!</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to navigate on path by button click in react router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877821/how-to-navigate-on-path-by-button-click-in-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not giving the target path in the button that's why it is not redirecting you anywhere.

Try by replacing your home component with below one.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className='container pt-5 text-center'>
      <Link to='/contact' className='btn btn-primary' >Click here</Link>
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

in your button in your Home.js replace

```
<button className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
```

with

```
<a href='/contact' class='btn btn-primary' role="button">Click here</a>
```

this is the simplest solution based on the fact you are using bootstrap and routing /contact path to your contact component

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Conditionnal rendering](https://scotch.io/tutorials/7-ways-to-implement-conditional-rendering-in-react-applications)

```
<div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul className="navbar-nav">
        <li className="nav-item active">
            { if (this.props.location.pathname !== "/") {
                return <Link className='nav-link' to='/'>Home</Link>
            } else { 
                return <Link className='nav-link' to='/contact'>Contact</Link>
                }
            }
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Moreover you should probably be using an other syntax to register your routes :

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path='/' component="{Home}"/>
   <Route path='/contact' component="{Contact}"/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Hi @Baldrani in Output I have to see only Home Component.  If I click the button then only I want to see Contact Component. In Navbar I don't want to see Home and Contact Components.

Comment: Ho okay I understood, I've edited my answer @William