# Need help as sound won't play when pressing button HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Would anyone be able to help me here as I'm not quite sure what the problem is, I think it has something to do with placement of one of the lines.

https://jsfiddle.net/70kwwpqp/

```
<div class="animatedButton">

    <audio id="Sound" src="Sounds/beep.mp3"> </audio>

    <a href="Home.html">
    <button class="aButton" <onclick="playBeep()"> <img src="img/Home.png"> </button>
    </a>

  </div>

function playBeep ()
{

var sound = document.getElementById("aButton")
sound.play()

}
```

Comment: You've assigned the 'aButton' as a class for th button. Also a typo `<onclick` should just be `onclick`.

Comment: Buttons are not allowed inside links. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5

Comment: `aButton` is a class and you are using `getElementById`

Comment: I am now getting the error 
playBeep is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick, what does this mean? It appeared when I gave the button an id tag

Answer (score 1):

```html
  <audio id="audio" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
    <a onclick="playSound();"> Play</a>
    <script>
    function playSound() {
          var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
          sound.play();
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Pretty much done word for word everyone else has said but nothing else has worked.
I now get the Error: playBeep is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
Can you help me with that?

Comment: try different sound in src

Comment: That's because they changed the function name to "playSound()". Is that your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error and the JSFiddle highlights it for you. There should not be a `<` before `onclick`.

Also, you are getting the `button` and asking it to `play()`. You should be getting the audio element by id `Sound` and playing that.

Comment: Ive done that but I still get an error
playBeep is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: Updated with another issue you probably need to fix. Lmk if there are more. @CaseyKusella-Gussin