# Getting random link after buttons div

Tags: html, css

No matter what I put after these buttons, the content under them is also a button. What am I missing? You can see on my current site - the footer is after the button so there's a half footer that links to google (same place as the buttons).

http://staging.yodega.com/sell

Would include a screenshot but that won't really convey it.

Relevant code attached.

```css
/* formats buttons on sell page */
#buttons {
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
#button1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 25px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px; 
    border: 0px solid #800000;
    color:#F0E8E0;
    background-color:#3a3a3a;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
#button2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 25px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px; 
    border: 0px solid #800000;
    color:#F0E8E0;
    background-color:#3a3a3a;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="astericks">

*Base rate starts at 5.5% and can be lowered via referrals. Learn more on the <a href="yodega.com/referrals">referrals</a> page
    
    </div>

<div id="buttons">
  <a href="http://www.google.com"><button type="button contact-button" id="button1">Sign Up</button>
  <a href="http://www.google.com"><button type="button contact-button" id="button2">Seller Resources</button
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an improperly closed `<button>` tag. I've updated `</button` to `</button>` in the below snippet. You also never close your `<a>` tags, that has also been updated.

As a heads up it is not valid HTML to have a button tag nested inside of an anchor tag. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393863/1168379 if you want it to look like a button, but function like a link then update the snippet so that `<button>` is removed and `<a>` has all the styling you want done to make it look like a button.

```css
/* formats buttons on sell page */
#buttons {
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
#button1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 25px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px; 
    border: 0px solid #800000;
    color:#F0E8E0;
    background-color:#3a3a3a;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
#button2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 25px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px; 
    border: 0px solid #800000;
    color:#F0E8E0;
    background-color:#3a3a3a;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="astericks">

*Base rate starts at 5.5% and can be lowered via referrals. Learn more on the <a href="yodega.com/referrals">referrals</a> page
    
    </div>

<div id="buttons">
  <a href="http://www.google.com"><button type="button contact-button" id="button1">Sign Up</button></a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com"><button type="button contact-button" id="button2">Seller Resources</button></a>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help! Changing this has resolved the extra link issue but has now caused the buttons to stack instead of be horizontal with one another. How could I get that back? Maybe making the "correct" button that you linked would help this.

Comment: @JacobJordan On your website you added a `<br />` between the buttons. This would be the cause of the buttons being on two lines. It would, however, be best if you removed the `<button>` element all together and just used `<a>` tags to do what you need. I would make a CSS class for `a.button` and then apply the stylings you want to match what you currently have. That way you're also not duplicating the same CSS for button1 and button2

Comment: Awesome - thanks for your help. Will do in the am!
What is a <br />? I don't believe I have added that. (I currently have two sets of buttons as Im testing them out - but both are stacking).

Comment: @JacobJordan If you look at lines 334-335 in your site's HTML source (may vary, especially as time goes on). You have your two buttons `<a href="http://www.google.com"><button type="button contact-button" id="button1">Sign Up</button></a><br />
  <a href="http://www.google.com"><button type="button contact-button" id="button2">Seller Resources</button></a>`. In the middle on Line 334 (or the first button) you have a `<br/>` tag being used. `<br/>` is used to start a new line in HTML, generally within a content tag (i.e. `p`, `h1`,  `h2`, `span`, ...)

Comment: That's very interesting cause there's no <br/> in my code. I wonder if this is some type of browser interpretation.

<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="buttons">
  <a href="http://www.google.com"><button type="button contact-button" id="button1">Sign Up</button></a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com"><button type="button contact-button" id="button2">Seller Resources</button></a>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

Comment: If it were a browser interpretation then it wouldn't show up in raw HTML source and would only show up in the DOM. If you're using a [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) to insert your HTML on the page then it may be adding it for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :)
You were opening `<a>` tags but closing with `<button>`.

```
<div id="buttons">
  <a href="http://www.google.com" id="button1">Sign Up</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com" id="button2">Seller Resources</a>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

I say leave it as an `<a>` as they are easier to use within html. 
try:

```
    #buttons {
      color: blue;
      padding: 20px;
      box-shadow: 
       0 1px 2px #fff, /*bottom external highlight*/
       0 -1px 1px #666, /*top external shadow*/ 
       inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), /*bottom internal shadow*/ 
       inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8); /*top internal highlight*/
       }
```

for an appearance like a button

Also..

```
<div class="astericks">

*Base rate starts at 5.5% and can be lowered via referrals. Learn more on the <a href="yodega.com/referrals">referrals</a> page

    </div>
```

It's good practice to declare what you've written in the div with an element. Is it a `<p>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, ect.

Hope this helps!