# How do you style <a> tags without affecting <button> tags that have a link?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering as to how you could style `<a>` tags without affecting `<button>` tags.

```css
a:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mrredblob.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/homework/style.css">
<a href="#"><button>A link</button></a>
```

Comment: Better to add sample code or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) to the question.Then question become more clear and easy to answer

Comment: Style on `a` tags do not affect the `button` tags unless you want them to. If you are facing such a problem, please post relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: How does that affect the button tags? Your question is still unclear.

Comment: Don't put <button>s inside <a>s. Just don't. I don't know who came up with this antipattern, but it's plain wrong.

Comment: Here's more information on what @MrLister said: [Can I nest a <button> inside an <a> using HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393863).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing it! Here's how:

```
a:not(button) {
   text-decoration: underline
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use a `button` like display for an anchor - such that clicking on it should redirect to another page, you could use something like this:

```
<button onclick="location.href='https://www.google.com'">A link</button>
```

The `onclick` event will execute when the user clicks the button, and redirects the user to appropriate page.

You can see it working by pasting the following in a new tab in your browser:

```
data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<button onclick="location.href='https://www.google.com'">A link</button>
```

<sub>It won't work in the snippets/JS Fiddle due to ~sandbox constraints on snippet's iframe.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">
    <button>
        <span>A link</span>
    </button>
</a>`
```

**CSS**

```
span:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The anchor tag's content in your example is a button, and you're trying to set the text decoration of a button, which is not text. The button contains text, but that text is a child of the button, and the button is a child of the anchor. Therefore, the anchor does not have a text value to apply that css property.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

**HTML**

`<a href="#">Here is<button>A link</button>Some text</a>`

**CSS**

```
a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Additionally, you can apply a wrapper class to your anchor to style the child elements:

```
.wrapper:hover * {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/foozie3moons/pen/gGRBxZ

Answer (score 0):

Try simply doing this :

```
<button><a href="#">A link</a></button>
```

This way you can style the text inside of the button however you want.

Comment: Please don't advise this. An `a`-element inside a `button` is not valid HTML as a `button`-elements [can't have interactive content descendants](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-button-element.html#the-button-element).