# AngularJS does not like the a tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Problem:** I have the following code which works fine:

```
<div style="margin-top: 5pt;">
     <a href="{{e.DocURL}}" target="_blank">
         <button class="btn btn-primary" 
                 id="showDocs" 
                 ng-show="e.DocFlag === 'Y'" 
                 style="border-radius: 13px; padding-bottom: 5px;" 
                 type="button">Provider Bio
         </button>
     </a>
</div>
```

However, whenever I update the form, the a tag goes disappears. I'm still fairly new to AngularJS and is their a alternative to the a tag I can use.

Comment: what value does e.DocFlag have?

Comment: It looks like the error may not be where you expect; does `e.DocFlag` change when the form is updated?

Comment: @MarkS.: e.DocFlag contains pdf files that will display depending on the name of a person. e.DocFlag does change if you are looking up a different person who may or may not have a pdf file

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not wrap the button with an `<a>` but put the "btn btn-primary" class in the `<a>`. HTML may not allow a link to contain a button.

Edit: This is confirmed by this answer: [Can I nest a <button> element inside an <a> using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5)

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` tag is not disappearing your button is. Look at this line:

```
ng-show="e.DocFlag === 'Y'"
```

When e.DocFlag is anything other than 'Y' the button will disappear. The button is the only thing inside the `a` tag. when there is nothing inside the `a` it will *appear* to be gone.

Comment: Let me elaborate: The actual a tag in the code disappears. Yes, the ng-show part will make it disappear. But the actual a tag is removed when I go back in the form

Comment: Would the following approach then work to prevent the disappearing of the a tag: '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{e.DocURL}}" id="showDocs" ng-show="e.DocFlag === 'Y'" style="border-radius: 13px; padding-bottom: 5px;" target="_blank" type="button">Provider Bio</a>'