# Query string not visible after using anchor tag on submit button

Tags: html

I am new to programming and was going through forms in HTML and I was looking if I use a submit button I can see the query string having the values of my text boxes(because the default method is GET), now I tried enclosing the submit button within an anchor tag and now I can't see the query string although, the method  I have chosen is GET. Also I know I can achieve a redirection by using ACTION but I am deliberately not doing that.

My question is, why does the query string disappear when I use an anchor tag around submit button?

Code:

```
<form method="get">
FirstName<br>
<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
LastName<br>
<input type="text" name="lname"><br>
<a href="testpage.php"><input type="submit" name="sub" value="submit"></a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit button inside anchor tag isn't a valid HTML5 according to the [HTML5 Spec Document from W3C](http://w3c.github.io/html/#the-a-element)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393863/5798881)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't have reputation points enough to upvote you but I have marked your answer.